# eval and quote in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What am I missing here?

```
d = data.table(a = 1:5)

d[, a]                   # 1 2 3 4 5
d[, sum(a)]              # 15

d[, eval(quote(a))]      # 1 2 3 4 5
d[, sum(eval(quote(a)))] # 15

quoted_a = quote(a)
d[, eval(quoted_a)]      # 1 2 3 4 5
d[, sum(eval(quoted_a))] # Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

What is going on? I'm running `R 2.15.0` and `data.table 1.8.9`.

Comment: I had a problem like this today; was solved by using `quote(sum(a))` instead of `expression(sum(a))`. No idea why it mattered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE (eddi):** As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=991) this has been fixed and `.SD` is not needed in cases where the expression can be evaluated in place, like in OP. Since currently presence of `.SD` triggers construction of full `.SD`, this will result in much faster speeds in some cases.

---

What's going on is that calls to `eval()` are treated differently than you likely imagine in the code that implements `[.data.table()`.  Specifically, `[.data.table()` contains special evaluation branches for `i` and `j` expressions that begin with the symbol `eval`. When you wrap the call to `eval` inside of a call to `sum()`, `eval` is no longer the first element of the parsed/substituted expression, and the special evaluation branch is skipped.

Here is the bit of code in the monster function displayed by typing `getAnywhere("[.data.table")` that makes a special allowance for calls to `eval()` passed in via `[.data.table()`'s `j`-argument:

```
jsub = substitute(j)
    ...
    # Skipping some lines
    ...
jsubl = as.list.default(jsub)
if (identical(jsubl[[1L]], quote(eval))) {  # The test for eval 'on the outside' 
    jsub = eval(jsubl[[2L]], parent.frame(), parent.frame())
    if (is.expression(jsub)) 
        jsub = jsub[[1L]]
}
```

As a workaround, either follow the example in data.table FAQ 1.6 ([pdf here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)), or explicitly point `eval()` towards `.SD`, the local variable that holds columns of whatever data.table you are operating on (here `d`). (For some more explanation of `.SD`'s role, see the first few paragraphs of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667984/can-sd-be-viewed-from-a-browser-within-data-table/15668311#15668311)).

```
d[, sum(eval(quoted_a, envir=.SD))]
```

Comment: ok, how can I fix this? I'd like to pass a `data.table` and a variable name to a function that would compute e.g. the `sum`. I was using the above code before (and I could swear it used to work with a previous version of either `R` or `data.table`), but that seems to be out of the question ...?

Comment: How about `quoted_a <- quote(sum(a))` as shown in the [**faq 1.6**](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)?

Comment: that won't work for me, whoever is calling the function doesn't know what kind of evaluations are going to happen there

Comment: @eddi -- use the correct environment for `eval` when not using the special case in `[.data.table` ([this answer]n(http://stackoverflow.com/a/11874464/1385941) may be useful (using `sum(eval(quoted_a,.SD))` will work....)

Comment: @mnel, how can one get the environment where the `expr` is to be evaluated? I mean, how did you get to `.SD` here? I tried with `parent.frame()` and it gave the same error. Any (other) references?

Comment: @Arun -- Are you saying this gives you an error? `d[, sum(eval(quoted_a, .SD))]`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, no, it works perfectly. My question is how to find out that the "envir" argument is `.SD` here... That is, I tried `d[, sum(eval(quoted_a, parent.frame()))]` and it gave the same error.. Perhaps I'm confused about the concept of `parent.frame()`.

Comment: @Arun -- Oh, I see. I think you just have to know about `.SD`'s central role in evaluation of all `i` and `j` expressions. The opening notes in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667984/can-sd-be-viewed-from-a-browser-within-data-table/15668311#15668311) should make it pretty clear why `.SD` is the environment you want. I expect that you can't find this out via calls to `parent.frame()` because `[.data.table` sidesteps/reroutes some of R's typical scoping rules.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, that answers my question. Thank you. However, (another hidden question) without knowing `.SD` is the environment, can we get the "environment" of expressions executed in `j` to be `.SD`. That is, can we using R-commands "discover" the environment of where an expression is executed.. I am beginning to think that I am making less sense with this question, but had to ask.

Comment: @Arun -- You're making plenty of sense. **data.table**'s power comes at the cost to its users of having to build a whole additional model of how its magic "really" happens. I'm still on the steep part of that learning curve myself ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  Agreed, that's true of advanced users. But most users can just follow the idiomatic patterns (hopefully?) without having to know how it really happens.

Comment: For all that, I submit that `data.table` should not do anything that breaks the expected behavior of nested functions at the command line. if `regular_matrix[,sum(eval(quoted_a))]` "works," then `data.table`'s failure to do so should be considered a bug.

Comment: @Carl I agree. The `data.frame` analog of the above: `with(data.frame(d), sum(eval(quoted_a)))` works as expected. lol, in fact `with(d, sum(eval(quoted_a)))` also works as expected.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- For the most part I agree, and I wouldn't go nearly so far as to call data.table's behavior a bug, but it definitely does violate the principle of least surprise in a few places. (Maybe it has to, though. I was actually diving into `[.data.table` to test out some ideas about possible alternatives when I ran into the problem reported in [my question of a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931801/why-does-trace-edit-true-not-work-when-data-table)!)