# Why does trace(..., edit=TRUE) not work when ... = [.data.table

Tags: r, data.table, trace

To temporarily edit the body of a packaged function `func`, I frequently use `trace(func, edit=TRUE)`.  For some reason, though, R isn't letting me do this when `func` is `[.data.table`:

```
## Note: In this and the other cases below, once an editor pops up, I save and 
## and then exit without making any edits to the function. The commented-out
## message below each call to trace() is what is then printed to my R console.

trace("[.data.table", where=data.table, edit=TRUE)
# Error in .makeTracedFunction(def, tracer, exit, at, print, doEdit) : 
#   the editing in trace() can only change the body of the function, not 
#   the arguments or defaults
```

**Questions:** What might be causing this error? What other functions also trigger it? For such functions, is there some alternative work-around that will allow me to edit them?

FWIW, this doesn't seem to be some general issue with functions in **data.table**'s namespace (see e.g. `#1` below) nor is it an issue with subset methods in general (see e.g. `#2` below).

```
## (#1)     
trace("within.data.table", where=data.table, edit=TRUE)
# Tracing function "within.data.table" as seen from package "data.table"
# [1] "within.data.table"

## (#2)
trace("[.Date", edit=TRUE)
# Tracing function "[.Date" in package "base"
# [1] "[.Date"
```

I am running `R-3.0.0` and `data.table_1.8.8` on a Windows XP machine, and get the same error whether I use set `options(editor="emacs")`, `options(editor="notepad")` or use the R GUI's default editor.

Comment: It works for me on 2.15.3 with data.table_1.8.6, Windows 7

Comment: However, I get the same error after upgrading to 1.8.8.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde -- Thanks! That really helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: I also get the same error after further upgrading to 1.8.9. Haven't yet tried 1.8.6 or 1.8.7 to determine which version first exhibits the changed behavior w.r.t. `trace()`.

Comment: Hi. Have skimmed commit logs and NEWS comparing 1.8.6 to 1.8.8 and the only things that spring to mind are that `rolltolast` has moved after `drop=NULL`, and `rollends` has been added which has a default that works in a new style by calling `c()`. Something to do with that maybe since the error message mentions arguments and defaults, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew . I'd like to have a look at that. Is there some place on the R-forge website where I can view a visual diff of the different commits? Or can I download the entire (SVN? Mercurial? git?) repository, to use vdiff tools on my own box?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  Sure, you can point SVN at `svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/datatable/`, anonymously.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I figured out what's causing `trace()` to choke, and I'm pretty sure you could solve it just by removing the the two braces from the `rollends` argument's default value. (They're useful indications of grouping for human readers but I don't think they're needed in this case for the computer to follow the right flow control path.)

Comment: Good stuff! `{}` now removed and committed, rev 854. R-Forge should pick it up and rebuild v1.8.9 in a few hours.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Thanks. Just downloaded your commit, with the once-again `trace`able `[.data.table`. Looking forward to playing around with it a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently being caused by the recent addition of curly braces (i.e. `{}`) at one place in `data.table`'s formal argument list.

First, a MRE to show that braces really do cause `trace(..., edit=TRUE)` to choke:

```
## Without braces, no problem
func <- function(inColor=FALSE, col = if(inColor) "red" else "grey") { 
    plot(rnorm(99), col=col)}

trace(func, edit=TRUE)
# [1] "func"


## With braces, tracing fails
funcB <- function(inColor=FALSE, col = if(inColor) "red" else {"grey"}) { 
    plot(rnorm(99), col=col)}

trace(funcB, edit=TRUE)
# Error in .makeTracedFunction(def, tracer, exit, at, print, doEdit) : 
#   the editing in trace() can only change the body of the function, not 
#   the arguments or defaults
```

Then, for the record, here are the formals for `[.data.table` in versions 1.8.6 (for which tracing works) and version 1.8.8 (for which it doesn't):

```
## Version 1.8.6 -- Tracing worked
function (x, i, j, by, keyby, with=TRUE, nomatch=getOption("datatable.nomatch"), 
    mult="all", roll=FALSE, rolltolast=FALSE, 
    which=FALSE, .SDcols, verbose=getOption("datatable.verbose"), drop=NULL)


## Version 1.8.8 -- Tracing doesn't (See {} in the 'rollends' argument)
function (x, i, j, by, keyby, with=TRUE, nomatch=getOption("datatable.nomatch"), 
    mult = "all", roll = FALSE, 
    rollends = if (roll == "nearest") c(TRUE, 
        TRUE) else {
        if (roll >= 0) 
            c(FALSE, TRUE)
        else c(TRUE, FALSE)
    }, 
    which = FALSE, .SDcols, verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose"), 
    allow.cartesian = getOption("datatable.allow.cartesian"), 
    drop = NULL, rolltolast = FALSE)
```

Comment: If somebody would be interested in preconfigured *trace* for `[.data.table` I built it as [dtq](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq) package, It is also faster than using `trace`.