# Simplify the code by using one of R's apply functions

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I cannot find a satisfying tutorial that would explain me how to use all the possibilities of apply functions. I'm still a newbie but this could often come in handy and significantly simplify my code. So here's my example...
I've got a data frame which looks like this:

```
> head(p01)
   time key dwell
1   8.13   z  0.00
3   8.13   x  1.25
5   9.38   l  0.87
7  10.25   x  0.15
9  10.40   l  1.13
11 11.53   x  0.45
```

get it into R:

```
p01 <- structure(list(time = c(8.13, 8.13, 9.38, 10.25, 10.4, 11.53), 
key = c("z", "x", "l", "x", "l", "x"), dwell = c(0, 1.25, 
0.869, 0.15, 1.13, 0.45)), .Names = c("time", "key", "dwell"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to count the occurences of each letter in `p01$key` and print them in `p01$occurences`, so that the result would look like this:

```
    time key dwell occurences
1   8.13   z  0.00          1
3   8.13   x  1.25          3
5   9.38   l  0.87          2
7  10.25   x  0.15          3
9  10.40   l  1.13          2
11 11.53   x  0.45          3
```

The way I do it now is:

```
p01[p01$key == "l", "occurences"] <- table(p01$key)["l"]
p01[p01$key == "x", "occurences"] <- table(p01$key)["x"]
p01[p01$key == "z", "occurences"] <- table(p01$key)["z"]
```

...which of course is not the best solution. Especially since the real data contains more possibilities in `p01$key` (one of 16 different letters).

On top of that I want to calculate total `dwell` for each letter, so what I'm doing now is:

```
p01[p01$key == "l", "total_dwell"] <- tapply(p01$dwell, p01$key, sum)["l"]
p01[p01$key == "x", "total_dwell"] <- tapply(p01$dwell, p01$key, sum)["x"]
p01[p01$key == "z", "total_dwell"] <- tapply(p01$dwell, p01$key, sum)["z"]
```

in order to get:

```
    time key dwell total_dwell
1   8.13   z  0.00        0.00
3   8.13   x  1.25        1.85
5   9.38   l  0.87        2.00
7  10.25   x  0.15        1.85
9  10.40   l  1.13        2.00
11 11.53   x  0.45        1.85
```

I've been googling and going through couple of books for the last 6 hours. Will really appreciate an elegant solution and/or a link to some comprehansive tutorial.
My solution is obviously working, but it's not the first time I have to go around the problem like this and my script files are starting to look ridiculous!

Comment: I"m sure someone will write you up an answer for this, but [this](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) is a fairly comprehensive treatment for this type of task. The only omission would be the **data.table** package, probably.

Comment: My attempt at describing how to convert loops to functions in general: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `plyr`:

```
res = ddply(p01, .(key), transform, 
                           occurrences = length(key), 
                           total_dwell = sum(dwell))
res
   time key dwell occurrences total_dwell
1  9.38   l 0.869           2       1.999
2 10.40   l 1.130           2       1.999
3  8.13   x 1.250           3       1.850
4 10.25   x 0.150           3       1.850
5 11.53   x 0.450           3       1.850
6  8.13   z 0.000           1       0.000
```

Do note that after this, the table is alphabetically sorted on `key`. You could use `order` to resort for `time`:

```
res[order(res$time),]
   time key dwell occurrences total_dwell
3  8.13   x 1.250           3       1.850
6  8.13   z 0.000           1       0.000
1  9.38   l 0.869           2       1.999
4 10.25   x 0.150           3       1.850
2 10.40   l 1.130           2       1.999
5 11.53   x 0.450           3       1.850
```

Comment: +1 I really like these one-liners in plyr and friends. I am still learning to use these over base R.

Comment: Sooo fast! you beat me! +1 ;)

Comment: Plyr is really nice yes, but a bit slow if the data becomes big. When this is the case, `data.table` is the answer...

Comment: ...and just add `total_dwell = sum(dwell)` to include that column as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've accepted this answer only because plyr requires a shorter input and together with the paper suggested by joran it should solve many of my past and future problems :)
data.table looks very neat too, and perhaps even more intuitive for a beginner. But I'll give plyr a chance first :) cheers guys.

Comment: ok, but as I said this post is more about learning how to solve similar problems in the future than a one-off solution and Wickham's paper attached describes plyr

Comment: ime you'll get a lot more mileage out of `data.table` for your future needs

Comment: @eddi depends, if your datasets are relatively small (~100k rows) the advantage of data.table is probably going to be modest. In this case plyr solutions will either be comparably fast, or acceptably fast. But I think `data.table` is an awesome tool to learn

Comment: Just as a remark, also take a look at `mutate` and `summarise`. These also work really well with `ddply`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra ok, so what you're saying is that for smaller datasets `data.table` is only *a little* better than `plyr` and so `plyr` is better to use for smaller datasets? :) Again, im(admittedly limited)e, `plyr` only has a few functions to offer that don't have an analog in `data.table` (e.g. `rbind.fill`), and in every other scenario it's slower and has more cumbersome syntax.

Comment: What can I say - I promise to have a look at both! :) thanks again guys.

Comment: @eddi plyr generalises in different directions to data table. e.g. if you want to fit a linear model to multiple subsets, then extract the coefficients then join them back together, I don't data.table is as helpful. Also data.table does a lot of magic behind the scenes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913832 which makes it harder to predict what it will do.

Comment: @hadley thanks, after this question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153947/when-is-plyr-better-than-data-table to understand a little better what I'm missing out on. The "feature" you point out is I believe a bug and should be fixed :)

Answer (score 10):

If your dataset is huge, try data.table.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(p01)
DT[,occurences:=.N,by=key]
DT[,total_dwell:=sum(dwell),by=key]

    time key dwell occurences total_dwell
1:  8.13   z 0.000          1       0.000
2:  8.13   x 1.250          3       1.850
3:  9.38   l 0.869          2       1.999
4: 10.25   x 0.150          3       1.850
5: 10.40   l 1.130          2       1.999
6: 11.53   x 0.450          3       1.850
```

---

The two lines of assigning by reference can be combined as follows:

```
DT[, `:=`(occurences = .N, total_dwell = sum(dwell)), by=key]
```

Comment: Of course you could also use `data.table` for small datasets :). But the `plyr` syntax looks easier to learn to me (note I heavily use `plyr` and no `data.table` just yet).

Comment: Actually, when you get used to it, data.table syntax is easier for this kind of operation.

Comment: What is easier to read is also a matter of taste probably, but `data.table` looks like an awesome package.

Comment: you can do both at the same time, using quoted `:=` (can't figure out how to type that in comment-space), and you should use `.N` instead of `length(time)`

Comment: The downside of data.table is that it works completely differently to most other types of objects in R, so you have to learn two ways of thinking about things: the usual R way and the data.table way.  The advantage is that this allows data.table to be very fast, but the disadvantage is a higher cognitive overhead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to use `apply` here. How about `table` to get the frequencies then use `match` to assign the frequencies to your table:

```
freq <- as.data.frame( table(p01$key) )
    # Var1 Freq
#1    l    2
#2    x    3
#3    z    1

p01$occurences <- freq[ match(p01$key , freq[,1] ) , 2 ]
p01
#   time key dwell occurences
#1   8.13   z 0.000          1
#3   8.13   x 1.250          3
#5   9.38   l 0.869          2
#7  10.25   x 0.150          3
#9  10.40   l 1.130          2
#11 11.53   x 0.450          3
```

As far as I can tell, the only advantage of this method over `plyr` solution is that the original ordering of your dataframe is retained. I do not know if you can specify this in the `ddply` function however (probably you can!).

Comment: +1 The order is fixed quite easily by sorting after the analysis.

Comment: (+1) @PaulHiemstra, I think what Simon was telling is that you can't get an "unsorted" solution from plyr. But you can have both from this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can naturally solve this problem with tapply.
Note that these makes a new object p01.summary, rather than adding to your object, p01.
Another line of code could fix that

```
p01.summary = with(p01, cbind(occurences=table(key),total.dwell=tapply(dwell,key,sum)))
```

or

```
p01.summary = with(p01, do.call(rbind,tapply(dwell,key,function(KEY){
   data.frame(occurence=length(KEY),total.dwell= sum(KEY))
}) ))
```