# when is plyr better than data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Better here can mean faster or easier to read/shorter syntax or it could also mean that the command is not even doable in `data.table`.

I don't use `plyr` a lot and would like to know if there are cases when I should. Because I don't use it a lot, the only example I can come up with is `rbind.fill` that to my knowledge doesn't have a `data.table` analog and every other example I've seen of smth being done in both `plyr` and `data.table`, the latter was faster and easier to read/more compact.

Comment: This is _way_ too broad.

Comment: **plyr** will not (in general) be faster than **data.table**. Some people (like myself) find the former's syntax far more intuitive and readable than the latter. But that is merely a subjective choice.

Comment: @Arun thx, I'll take a look at those functions. Does `plyr` do anything for `data.frame`'s better?

Comment: @Arun, cool thanks. The parallel stuff sounds interesting, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Just my 2ct, for multidimensional array's plain `array` is much faster that `aaply`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are different packages with different purposes. One is not a substitute for the other, despite there being a small subset of functionality for which they overlap.

Here is the brief summary of each package, from the packages themselves:

> The plyr package is a set of clean and consistent tools that implement the split-apply-combine pattern in R. This is an extremely common pattern in data analysis: you solve a complex problem by breaking it down into small pieces, doing something to each piece and then combining the results back together again.

and

> `data.table` ... offers fast subset, fast grouping, fast update, fast ordered joins and list columns in a short and flexible syntax, for faster development. It is inspired by A[B] syntax in R where A is a matrix and B is a 2-column matrix.

Where they overlap is in the "fast grouping" which plyr also does by splitting data.frames, operating on pieces, and recombining them into a single data.frame.  `data.table` has many other features which make operations on data.frame like structures fast; `plyr` has features which apply the split-apply-combine paradigm to other data structures such as lists and arrays (both as inputs and outputs).

So, really, they are two different tools that happen to have a small area of overlap which address the same problem domain, but each does much more than that and if you want/need that additional functionality, then that package should be used.

Comment: sounds like you're saying that `plyr` does some things that `data.table` can't - that's exactly what I'm looking for - can you please give an example or two? thanks

Comment: `library("plyr"); example("llply")` Or really, any of the `**ply` functions other than `ddply`.

Comment: `llply` doesn't seem like a good one for this purpose (as far I see it does very little on top of what `lapply` already does), but the other ones do, I'll take a look at those functions and maybe resurrect this question after that, for now this'll do, thanks