# fast frequency and percentage table with dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have been using a small `tab` function for some time, which shows the frequency, percent, and cumulative percent for a vector. The output looks like this

```
          Freq    Percent        cum
ARSON      462 0.01988893 0.01988893
BURGLARY 22767 0.98011107 1.00000000
         23229 1.00000000         NA
```

The excellent `dplyr` package motivated me to update the function. Now I am wondering how I can make the updated version even faster. Here is the old function

```
tab = function(x,useNA =FALSE) {
  k=length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))+1
  if (useNA) k=k+1
  tab=array(NA,c(k,3))
  colnames(tab)=c("freq.","prob.","cum.")
  useNA=ifelse(useNA,"always","no")
  rownames(tab)=names(c(table(x,useNA=useNA),""))

  tab[-nrow(tab),1]=table(x,useNA=useNA)
  tab[-nrow(tab),2]=prop.table(table(x,useNA=useNA))
  tab[,3] = cumsum(tab[,2])
  if(k>2)  tab[nrow(tab),-3]=colSums(tab[-nrow(tab),-3])
  if(k==2) tab[nrow(tab),-3]=tab[-nrow(tab),-3]

  tab
}
```

and the new based on `dplyr`

```
tab2 = function(x, useNA =FALSE) {
    if(!useNA) if(any(is.na(x))) x = na.omit(x)
    n = length(x)
    out = data.frame(x,1) %.%
        group_by(x) %.%
        dplyr::summarise(
            Freq    = length(X1),
            Percent = Freq/n
        ) %.%
        dplyr::arrange(x)
    ids = as.character(out$x)
    ids[is.na(ids)] = '<NA>'
    out = select(out, Freq, Percent)
    out$cum = cumsum(out$Percent)
    class(out)="data.frame"
    out = rbind(out,c(n,1,NA))
    rownames(out) = c(ids,'')
    out
}
```

Finally, some performance benchmarks:

```
x1 = c(rep('ARSON',462),rep('BURGLARY',22767))
x2 = c(rep('ARSON',462),rep('BURGLARY',22767),rep(NA,100))
x3 = c(c(1:10),c(1:10),1,4)
x4 = c(rep(c(1:100),500),rep(c(1:50),20),1,4)

library('rbenchmark')

benchmark(tab(x1), tab2(x1), replications=100)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#       test elapsed relative
# 1  tab(x1)   1.412    2.307
# 2 tab2(x1)   0.612    1.000

benchmark(tab(x2),tab2(x2), replications=100)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#       test elapsed relative
# 1  tab(x2)   1.351    1.475
# 2 tab2(x2)   0.916    1.000

benchmark(tab(x2,useNA=TRUE), tab2(x2,useNA=TRUE), replications=100)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#                     test elapsed relative
# 1  tab(x2, useNA = TRUE)   1.883    2.282
# 2 tab2(x2, useNA = TRUE)   0.825    1.000

benchmark(tab(x3), tab2(x3), replications=1000)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#       test elapsed relative
# 1  tab(x3)   0.997    1.000
# 2 tab2(x3)   2.194    2.201

benchmark(tab(x4), tab2(x4), table(x4), replications=100)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#        test elapsed relative
# 1   tab(x4)  19.481   18.714
# 2  tab2(x4)   1.041    1.000
# 3 table(x4)   6.515    6.258
```

`tab2` is faster except for the very short vector. The performance gain becomes evident in the larger vector (see `x4` with 51002 obs). It's also faster than `table` even thought the function is doing much more.

Now to my question: How can I further improve performance? Creating tables with frequencies and percent is a pretty standard application and a fast implementation is very nice when you work with large datasets.

**EDIT**: Here is an additional test case with a 2e6 vector (including the `data.table` solution proposed below)

```
x5 = sample(c(1:100),2e6, replace=TRUE)
benchmark(tab(x5), tab2(x5), table(x5), tabdt(x5), replications=100)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
#        test elapsed relative
# 1   tab(x5) 350.878   19.444
# 2  tab2(x5)  52.917    2.932
# 4 tabdt(x5)  18.046    1.000
# 3 table(x5)  98.429    5.454
```

Comment: these are all tiny vectors and take no time to run with base - is this really what you mean by large datasets (or are you running this operation in a loop)?

Comment: no, my actual data is between 1 and 5 mill rows. These are just test cases and the performance already becomes obvious in with `x4`, which has about 51000 obs)

Comment: ok, I suggest doing benchmarks on real-sized data, as various options can scale very differently from 50k to 5M

Comment: working on it right now and will update with a new case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I'm a big fan of `library(data.table)` I wrote similar function:

```
tabdt <- function(x){
    n <- length(which(!is.na(x)))
    dt <- data.table(x)
    out <- dt[, list(Freq = .N, Percent = .N / n), by = x]
    out[!is.na(x), CumSum := cumsum(Percent)]
    out
}

> benchmark(tabdt(x1), tab2(x1), replications=1000)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
       test elapsed relative
2  tab2(x1)    5.60    1.879
1 tabdt(x1)    2.98    1.000
> benchmark(tabdt(x2), tab2(x2), replications=1000)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
       test elapsed relative
2  tab2(x2)    6.34    1.686
1 tabdt(x2)    3.76    1.000
> benchmark(tabdt(x3), tab2(x3), replications=1000)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
       test elapsed relative
2  tab2(x3)    1.65    1.000
1 tabdt(x3)    2.34    1.418
> benchmark(tabdt(x4), tab2(x4), replications=1000)[,c('test','elapsed','relative')]
       test elapsed relative
2  tab2(x4)   14.35    1.000
1 tabdt(x4)   22.04    1.536
```

And so `data.table` approach was faster for `x1` and `x2` while `dplyr` was faster for `x3` and `x4`. Actually I don't see any room for improvement using these approaches.

p.s. Would you add `data.table` keyword to this question? I believe people would love to see `dplyr` vs. `data.table` performance comparison (see [data.table vs dplyr: can one do something well the other can't or does poorly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) for example).

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer with the actual benchmarks?  Unfortunately I'm having a hell of a time installing `dplyr` so I can't run them side by side (and confirm they are actually producing the same output).

Comment: @BrodieG what do you mean, you have hell of a time installing dplyr. What happens when you do `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: @RomainFrancois, for some reason (I could swear I read that someplace) I though this was a github release only so far and was running into issues with suggest dependencies.  The normal install works fine (need shoots-self-in-head emoticon).

Comment: Nice! I have added the keyword. I would argue that `tab2` does better though because its faster when it counts (for longer vectors). Even `x4` is not particular long---the others are just super short and will run very quickly anyway.

Comment: I have to take that back. Just added a new benchmark with 2e6 obs and your approach is faster. But your solution doesn't offer the `useNA` option and does not add a total column...

Comment: Actually it does handle `NA` values. You can see it by examining the output of `tabdt` function.

Comment: Your solution can be slightly improved in terms of performance: `tabdt2 <- function(x){
  NnotNA <- sum(!is.na(x)); setnames(setDT(list(x)),"x")[,list(Freq = .N, Percent = .N / NnotNA), by = x][!is.na(x), CumSum := cumsum(Percent)]
}`