# Merging two data.frames with two keys where one is the closest date

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge a column from `table2` onto `table1` using two keys. Where I'm having issues is that one of these keys is a date, and I don't always have an exact date match. So I'd like to match on the date from `table1` using the date from `table2` that is closest to that date but not "greater" than it. So if I have:

```
table1 <- data.frame(id1=c(30380,30380,30455,51949), date=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13 00:00:00","2012-09-23 00:00:00","2011-04-09 00:00:00","2014-11-08 00:00:00"))) 

table2 <- data.frame(id2=c(30380,30380,30380,30380,
                       30455,30455,
                       51949,51949,51949), 
                 date=as.POSIXct(c("2012-10-01 00:00:00","2012-08-31 00:00:00","2012-02-22 00:00:00","2011-08-30 00:00:00",
                                   "2011-08-30 00:00:00","2011-02-22 00:00:00",
                                   "2015-01-08 00:00:00","2014-08-24 00:00:00","2014-11-08 00:00:00")),
                 rating=c(77,79,82,80,80,81,78,79,77))
```

Then I would expect output:

```
output <- data.frame(id1=c(30380,30380,30455,51949), 
                 date=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13 00:00:00","2012-09-23 00:00:00","2011-04-09 00:00:00","2014-11-08 00:00:00")),
                 rating=c(82,79,81,77))
```

I have tried using `data.table`'s `setDT()` roll option with no success. If it matters, I also plan on doing this over several columns, meaning I would create several `rating` columns since I actually have several `id1` columns. I thought figuring this out first would be a better start than attacking all of it. I'm really stuck, thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, read about roll-joins and join-on-intervals.

Comment: My understanding of roll-joins is definitely lacking. I think the question marked as duplicate is not similar to my question though as there are two keys. The answer to my question is best found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072542/merge-nearest-date-and-related-variables-from-a-another-dataframe-by-group

Comment: OK, added the link, if you still think this is not a duplicate, please vote to re-open.