# Unable to perform rolling join on time and another variable in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data.tables - one with location snapshots (`df2`), and one with times when rides ended (`df1`).  My goal is to join the very large `df2` on `df1` where the times match closest and the `bike_id`s match.   I have tried everything in `data.table` but nothing seems to work.

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072542/merge-nearest-date-and-related-variables-from-a-another-dataframe-by-group) almost verbatim to merge by `bike_id` and by nearest `time`, but I end up with empty columns.

```
sum(is.na(df1$time))
# [1] 0
sum(is.na(df2$time))
# [1] 0

sapply(df1, class)
# $time
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

# $bike_id
# [1] "integer"

sapply(df2, class)
# $time
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

# $bike_id
# [1] "integer"

# $st_x
# [1] "numeric"

# $st_y
# [1] "numeric"

all(df1$bike_id %in% df2$bike_id)
# [1] TRUE
```

Neither of the tables have `NA` in time value, and both contain the same `bike_id`s.

For example:

```
head(df1)
#                   time bike_id
# 1: 2017-12-20 07:29:22   16465
# 2: 2017-12-20 15:34:36   16465
# 3: 2017-12-09 22:08:56   16468
# 4: 2017-12-10 12:38:53   16468
# 5: 2017-12-18 00:19:18   16468
# 6: 2017-12-18 17:29:18   16468


head(df2)
#                   time bike_id      st_x     st_y
# 1: 2017-12-04 16:21:31   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
# 2: 2017-12-04 16:30:05   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
# 3: 2017-12-04 16:40:05   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
# 4: 2017-12-04 16:50:05   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
# 5: 2017-12-04 17:00:06   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
# 6: 2017-12-04 17:10:06   16465 -90.07687 29.95264
```

The code I am using to match by `bike_id` and by nearest `time` is:

```
setkey(df2, time, bike_id)[, dateMatch:=time]
test <- df2[df1, roll = 'nearest']


head(test)
#                   time bike_id st_x st_y dateMatch
# 1: 2017-12-20 07:29:22   16465   NA   NA      <NA>
# 2: 2017-12-20 15:34:36   16465   NA   NA      <NA>
# 3: 2017-12-09 22:08:56   16468   NA   NA      <NA>
# 4: 2017-12-10 12:38:53   16468   NA   NA      <NA>
# 5: 2017-12-18 00:19:18   16468   NA   NA      <NA>
# 6: 2017-12-18 17:29:18   16468   NA   NA      <NA>
```

Any ideas as to what could possibly be going wrong? Substituting `roll=Inf` produces the same result with columns of `NA`s.

Wouldn't `roll='nearest'` find at least some date if `bike_id`s are the same in both tables and `time` is never `NA`?

Comment: could you add `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))` to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to solve the problem

```
test = df2[df1, on=.(bike_id, time = time), roll="nearest", 
            .(bike_id, time, st_x, st_y)]
```