# Doing a left join with exact values plus closest values

Tags: r

I have two data sets:

```
table1 <- data.frame(id=c(1000,1001,1002,1003), 
                    date=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13","2012-09-23","2011-04-09","2014-11-08"))) 

table2 <- data.frame(id2=c(1000,1000,1001,1002,1003,1003), 
                   date2=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13","2012-05-16","2012-09-24","2011-04-15","2014-11-09", "2014-11-10")))
```

I want to do a left join on table1 based on matching ID and Date, however not all dates have an exact match so I was wondering how could I join the dates based on the closest day? For example for id 1001, "2012-09-23" would match "2012-09-24" for id2 1001 since it is the only date for id2 and for 1003 the "2014-11-08" would match "2014-11-09" of 1003 for id2 since it is the closest day.

Desired result:

```
  id       date      date2
1 1000 2012-05-13 2012-05-13
2 1001 2012-09-23 2012-09-24
3 1002 2011-04-09 2011-04-15
4 1003 2014-11-08 2014-11-09
```

Comment: fuzzyjoin is your friend. look up https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/README.html and look at this post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881/2

Comment: this is even easier! left_join(table1,table2, by=c("id" = "id2"))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge nearest date, and related variables from a another dataframe by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072542/merge-nearest-date-and-related-variables-from-a-another-dataframe-by-group)

Answer (score 4):

I'd also recommend you to follow the non-equi `data.table` joins, but in case you'd like to for whatever reason stick with `dplyr` and your data isn't really big or you have enough memory, you could also try:

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  left_join(table2, by = c("id" = "id2")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(date - date2)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
     id date                date2              
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1  1000 2012-05-13 00:00:00 2012-05-13 00:00:00
2  1001 2012-09-23 00:00:00 2012-09-24 00:00:00
3  1002 2011-04-09 00:00:00 2011-04-15 00:00:00
4  1003 2014-11-08 00:00:00 2014-11-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use data.table to perform a rolling join to the nearest value.
DT1 is updated by reference, so it shoul be very fast, even on large/big data

```
library(data.table)
```

**sample data**

```
dt1 <- as.data.table(table1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(table2)
```

**code**

```
dt1[, date2 := dt2[dt1, date2, on = c("id2 == id", "date2 == date"), roll = "nearest"]][]
```

**output**

```
#      id       date      date2
# 1: 1000 2012-05-13 2012-05-13
# 2: 1001 2012-09-23 2012-09-23
# 3: 1002 2011-04-09 2011-04-09
# 4: 1003 2014-11-08 2014-11-08
```

Comment: good answer but how would I account for the ID field? since the join is based on matching ID and the Date

Answer (score 1):

With advent of dplyr 1.1.0 that has gained two helper functions `join_by()` and `closest` it is now pretty easy

```r
table1 <- data.frame(id=c(1000,1001,1002,1003), 
                     date=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13","2012-09-23","2011-04-09","2014-11-08"))) 

table2 <- data.frame(id2=c(1000,1000,1001,1002,1003,1003), 
                     date2=as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-13","2012-05-16","2012-09-24","2011-04-15","2014-11-09", "2014-11-10"))) 
library(dplyr)
#> 

table1
#>     id       date
#> 1 1000 2012-05-13
#> 2 1001 2012-09-23
#> 3 1002 2011-04-09
#> 4 1003 2014-11-08
table2
#>    id2      date2
#> 1 1000 2012-05-13
#> 2 1000 2012-05-16
#> 3 1001 2012-09-24
#> 4 1002 2011-04-15
#> 5 1003 2014-11-09
#> 6 1003 2014-11-10

table1 %>% 
  left_join(table2, by = join_by(id == id2,
                                 closest(date <= date2)))
#>     id       date      date2
#> 1 1000 2012-05-13 2012-05-13
#> 2 1001 2012-09-23 2012-09-24
#> 3 1002 2011-04-09 2011-04-15
#> 4 1003 2014-11-08 2014-11-09
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>