In R: extracting data from a column based on closest date
I have two datasets. The first dataset is the main one, is wide, and has id as a unique/identifying variable. The second dataset has the same id variable, is long, and has multiple observations for id (i.e., id is not unique).
The second dataset only has three variables: id, date, and value. Id and date together also are not unique - there are repeated combinations. The value variable is a number. Annoyingly, some of the id/date repeats have different numbers in the value field, so I need to identify those so I can manually pick the value I need.
My ultimate goal is to copy the value field from the second dataset into the first, using the observation whose date is the closest to a key date from the first dataset. For example, say that in the first dataset, id==1 has a key date of 5/1/2024. Then in the second dataset, there is one row with id==1, date==4/30/2024, and value==3; and there is another row with id==1, date==5/5/2024, and value==4. I want 3 to be pulled into the first dataset into a new column for id==1.
https://github.com/markelphelps/sample-data-1
Check out the files in my github. The second dataset started as df2_long, and I tried to make it into df2_wide. Instead the best I could do was:
df_long2 <- reshape(df_long,
                       timevar = "date",
                       idvar = "id",
                       direction = "wide")

I hoped it would make two new columns, date and value. Instead it makes a new column for each unique date. Using pivot_wider gave me a list-col because of the repeats in date.
I do get the error “multiple rows for each date;” I’m guessing the easiest way to address that is to delete some before the reshape, but I’m not sure how. Something like “print each row of df where id’s are equal and date’s are equal.” Maybe something with a for loop or lapply/sapply that recycles the command for each unique id value.
Next I need to find closest date
which.min(abs(df1_main$key_date - df2_long$date))

I read that abs() was necessary to account for df2_long$date being sometimes before and sometimes after df1_main$key_date. But I get an error that says “abs not defined for “Date” objects.” When I take out abs(), the command returns “integer(0),” which doesn’t seem super useful.
The next step after finding that closest date is to do that for all id's, then turn them into a new variable.
edit: leaving work for the day, will check/respond to comments tomorrow
edit2: apologies for the mixup in df names, i forgot to rename the ones in my github. as you inferred df1_main == df ex_original; df2_long == df ex_long; and df3_wide == df ex_wide. I added the renamed versions (complete duplicates) in case that makes things more clear for anyone.
edit 3: thanks all, very informative! The best fit for my data was the comment from @Eugenio.Gastelum96 directing me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63754287/9588300. The comment by @teru to do leftjoin() with dplyr worked perfectly with the sample data. next week I'll try it on my real data and check back in if something else doesn't work.

Of the two dataframes on your git, I assume df ex_original.csv is the first dataframe  you describe in your first paragraph (i will call it df1). While df ex_long.csv is the second one (I will call it df2). If what you want is that df1 gets a new column that has the value from df2 for the same id and from the closest date to the one of df1, then you could do a join between them. But before that, I think it's important to note, in your example on df2 for id=6 you have two records on same date. Which of those 2 is the one you are expecting as the correct value to pick?

For the joining part I mentioned, here is one example on how to join two dataframes by using a "nearest date only" criteria on the join. There are also many other ways mentioned in that question, all have their plus and minus. If your dataframe are not every big and you have RAM avaiable the join solution in this link will do fine:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63754287/9588300

@Eugenio.Gastelum96, I'd first want to identify those observations and look at them individually so our team can figure it out. brandonEm commented explaning how to use the 'pivot_wider' error message to figure it out

Data table solution using a rolling join (returns the first record if there are ties):
library(data.table)

df_ex_original = fread("df ex_original.csv")
df_ex_long = fread("df ex_long.csv")

df_ex_original[, `:=`(key_date=as.Date(key_date, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
                     value=NULL)]

df_ex_long[, date:=as.Date(date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]

setkeyv(df_ex_original, c('id', 'key_date'))
setkeyv(df_ex_long, c('id', 'date'))

df_ex_long[df_ex_original, roll="nearest"]


Key: <id, date>
      id       date value
   <int>     <Date> <int>
1:     1 2024-01-06     3
2:     2 2024-01-01     1
3:     3 2024-01-10     1
4:     4 2024-01-12     0
5:     5 2024-01-14     6
6:     6 2024-01-02     5


Answering the comment:
data.table commands update by reference, so there's no need to use <-. See the help page for more details. It shows how to use := when updating multiple columns.
Assigning a variable to NULL effectively deletes that variable from the data and I didn't want the value variable in df1 since you wanted to obtain its values from df2. I could have used an update but this seemed like a better way to go.
In my as.Date() command, I had an inexcusable error. Sorry! Please replace "%M" with "%m".

thanks so much! looks like this will work. just a few clarifying questions:
'df_ex_original[, :=(key_date=as.Date(key_date, format="%M/%d/%Y"),
value=NULL)]' seems to change the dates. for example, for observation 1, the original date is Jan 6, 2024 and i think it gets changed to May 6, 2024.
how does the as.Date code change df_ex_original without starting with 'df_ex_original <-'?
what is the := operator, and why does it need to be inside single quotes?
what does the value=NULL argument do and why is it only needed for df1?

See my edit which hopefully answers your questions. Sorry about the dates. I had a typo.

hello again! in the final output, what would you change to include key_date from df_ex_original, instead of date from df_ex_long? @Edward

The output contains the values of key_date from df_ex_original but is called date because the variable name comes from df_ex_long. It is a very simple exercise to change the name. Either change it in df_ex_long, before the merge or after in the result.

I think there's two questions here, yeah?
First:
tidyr::pivot_wider has really good error messages that actually list code that you can use to debug, e.g:
Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} |>
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .by = c(id, date)) |>
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L) 

Where {data} is your data frame. Alternatively, you can summarize across your duplicates if you don't need to inspect them one-by-one, e.g.:
read.csv('df_ex_long.csv') |>
  dplyr::group_by(id, date) |>
  dplyr::summarize(value = mean(value)) |>
  dplyr::ungroup()

Second:
abs should totally work on Date-class objects:
Sys.Date() - (Sys.Date() - 5)
# Time difference of 5 days
Sys.Date() - (Sys.Date() + 5)
# Time difference of -5 days
abs(Sys.Date() - (Sys.Date() + 5))
# Time difference of 5 days

# OR:

time <- data.frame(t0 = c(Sys.Date() + seq(100)), t1 = c(Sys.Date() + rnorm(100, 50, 10)))
time$t1 - time$t0
abs(time$t1 - time$t0)

You can check your object classes with class (e.g. class(time$t1) and convert to others if necessary (e.g. ?as.POSIXct, ?as.POSIXlt, ?strptime).

Something you can try :
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

### Data
df_ex_original = read_csv("C:/Users/your_name/your_folder/df ex_original.csv")
df_ex_long = read_csv("C:/Users/your_name/your_folder/df ex_long.csv")

### Format correctly the columns which contain the dates
df1=df_ex_original %>% select(1,2) %>% mutate(key_date=mdy(key_date))
df2=df_ex_long %>% mutate(date=mdy(date))

### Join steps to find the closest date and the corresponding value for each id
### A count column has been added to identify duplicates
df1 %>%
  left_join(y = df2, by = join_by(id,closest(key_date<=date))) %>% 
  left_join(y = df2, by = join_by(id,closest(key_date>=date))) %>% 
  mutate(value=pmin(value.x,value.y,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(id,key_date,last_col()) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n=n())

Output :
# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   id [6]
     id key_date   value     n
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <int>
1     1 2024-01-06     3     1
2     2 2024-01-01     1     1
3     3 2024-01-10     1     1
4     4 2024-01-12     0     1
5     5 2024-01-14     6     1
6     6 2024-01-02     5     2
7     6 2024-01-02     1     2

