# How do I find the closest date to a given date?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I am trying to figure out how to find the closest date in 1 zoo object to a given date in another zoo object (could also use data.frame). Suppose I have:

```
dates.zoo <- zoo(data.frame(val=seq(1:121)), order.by = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-03-31'), "days"))
monthly.zoo <- zoo(data.frame(val=c(1,2,4)), order.by = c(as.Date('2018-12-14'), as.Date('2019-1-2'), as.Date('2019-2-3')))
```

For each date in `dates.zoo` I would like to align it with the closest previous date in `monthly.zoo`. (`NA` if no monthly date is found). So the data.frame/zoo object I am expecting is:

```
...
2018-12-02   2  NA
...
2018-12-14  14  2018-12-14
2018-12-15  15  2018-12-14
2018-12-16  16  2018-12-14
...
2019-01-01  32  2018-12-14
2019-01-02  33  2019-01-02
2019-01-03  34  2019-01-02
...
```

NOTE: I would prefer a Base-R solution but others would be interesting to see also

Comment: maybe useful :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342647/how-to-match-by-nearest-date-from-two-data-frames

Comment: would be interesting to see a generic form where it could easily be configured to be instead of just T-1 to be able to support T-2, T-3, ...

Comment: I'm sure there will be some clever way with data,table answer at the link^^. and with the base R answer I guess you could swap out the which.min part to select the second, third largest

Comment: Check `findInterval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following through on Henrik's suggestion to use `findInterval`. We can do:

```
library(zoo)
interval.idx <- findInterval(index(dates.zoo), index(monthly.zoo))
interval.idx <- ifelse(interval.idx == 0, NA, interval.idx)
dates.zoo$month <- index(monthly.zoo)[interval.idx]
```

Comment: This answer really needs to be marked as the accepted answer.  Reason: I think that all the other answers have performance of O(N) where N is the number of zoo indices that need to be searched thru.  In contrast, the [findInterval documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) says that it uses a fast log(N) algorithm (binary search?).

Answer (score 3):

A rolling join using data.table can be used.
See also: https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/

Also a solution using base-R

#### data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
dates.df <- data.table(val=seq(1:121), dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-03-31'), "days"))
monthly.df <- data.table(val=c(1,2,4,5), dates = c(as.Date('2018-12-14'), as.Date('2019-1-2'), as.Date('2019-2-3')))

setkeyv(dates.df,"dates")
setkeyv(monthly.df,"dates")

#monthly.df[,nearest:=(dates)][dates.df,roll = 'nearest'] #closest date
monthly.df[,nearest:=(dates)][dates.df,roll = Inf] #Closest _previous_ date
```

#### base R solution

```
dates.df <- zoo(data.frame(val=seq(1:121)), order.by = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-03-31'), "days"))
monthly.df <- zoo(data.frame(val=c(1,2,4)), order.by = c(as.Date('2018-12-14'), as.Date('2019-1-2'), as.Date('2019-2-3')))

dates.df <- data.frame(val=dates.df$val,dates=attributes(dates.df)$index)
monthly.df <- data.frame(val=monthly.df$val,dates=attributes(monthly.df)$index)

min_distances <- as.numeric(dates.df$dates)- matrix(rep(as.numeric(monthly.df$dates),nrow(dates.df)),ncol=length(monthly.df$dates),byrow=T)
min_distances <- as.data.frame(t(min_distances))

closest <- sapply(min_distances,function(x) 
  { 
    w <- which(x==min(x[x>0])); 
    ifelse(length(w)==0,NA,w) 
  })

dates.df$closest_month <- monthly.df$dates[closest]
```

#### Results: data.table

```
> monthly.df[,nearest:=(dates)][dates.df,roll = Inf]
     val      dates    nearest i.val
  1:  NA 2018-12-01       <NA>     1
  2:  NA 2018-12-02       <NA>     2
  3:  NA 2018-12-03       <NA>     3
  4:  NA 2018-12-04       <NA>     4
  5:  NA 2018-12-05       <NA>     5
 ---                                
118:   4 2019-03-27 2019-02-03   117
119:   4 2019-03-28 2019-02-03   118
120:   4 2019-03-29 2019-02-03   119
121:   4 2019-03-30 2019-02-03   120
122:   4 2019-03-31 2019-02-03   121
```

#### Results base R

```
> dates.df[64:69,]
           val      dates closest_month
2019-02-02  64 2019-02-02    2019-01-02
2019-02-03  65 2019-02-03    2019-01-02
2019-02-04  66 2019-02-04    2019-02-03
2019-02-05  67 2019-02-05    2019-02-03
2019-02-06  68 2019-02-06    2019-02-03
2019-02-07  69 2019-02-07    2019-02-03
```

Comment: Seems so and that I should have read more closely -- so a roll=Inf would be applicable here.  I'll adjust.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If, for each date in `dates.df`, you want to get the closest date in `monthly.df` which is less than the given date, and `monthly.df` is sorted by date ascending, you can use the method below. It counts the number of rows in `monthly.df` with index less than the given date, which is equivalent to the index if `mothly.df` is sorted by date ascending. If there are 0 such rows, the index is changed to `NA`.

```
inds <- rowSums(outer(index(dates.df), index(monthly.df), `>`))
inds[inds == 0] <- NA
dates.df_monthmatch <- index(monthly.df)[inds]


dates.df_monthmatch
#   [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
#   [7] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
#  [13] NA           NA           "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14"
#  [19] "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14"
#  [25] "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14"
#  [31] "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2018-12-14" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02"
#  [37] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02"
#  [43] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02"
#  [49] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02"
#  [55] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02"
#  [61] "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-02" "2019-02-03"
#  [67] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
#  [73] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
#  [79] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
#  [85] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
#  [91] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
#  [97] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
# [103] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
# [109] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
# [115] "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-03"
# [121] "2019-02-03"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility, although I did have to change the object to a data frame in order to assign the zoo index dates. This code compares the month, then year, and then finally day with criteria that it is less than or equal to the date to be matched against. If there is no date that matches this criteria then an NA is assigned. These comparisons were done with he package 'lubridate' checking for the individual date elements, and then which to logically index the best match.

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

dates.df <- zoo(data.frame(val=seq(1:121)), order.by = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-03-31'), "days"))
monthly.df <- zoo(data.frame(val=c(1,2,4)), order.by = c(as.Date('2018-12-14'), as.Date('2019-1-2'), as.Date('2019-2-3')))

month_m<-month(monthly.df)
month_d<-month(dates.df)

year_m<-year(monthly.df)
year_d<-year(dates.df)

day_m<-day(monthly.df)
day_d<-day(dates.df)

index<-list()
Index<-list()

for( i in 1:length(monthly.df)){

index[[i]]<-which(month_m[i] == month_d & year_m[i] == year_d
                  & day_d <= day_m[i])

test<-unlist(index[[i]])

   #Assigns NA if no suitable match is found
   if(length(test)==0){
    print("NA")
    Index[[i]]=NA
    }else {
    Index[[i]]<-tail(test, n=1)
    }                      
}

Test<-unlist(Index)
monthly.df_Fin<-as.data.frame(monthly.df)
dates.df_Fin<-as.data.frame(dates.df)
monthly.df_Fin$match<-as.character(row.names(dates.df_Fin)[Test])
monthly.df_Fin$value<-dates.df_Fin[Test,]

> monthly.df_Fin
           val      match value
2018-12-14   1 2018-12-14    14
2019-01-02   2 2019-01-02    33
2019-02-03   4 2019-02-03    65
```

Say we changed a value outside of the critera range:

```
monthly.df <- zoo(data.frame(val=c(1,2,4)), order.by = c(as.Date('2018-12- 
14'), as.Date('2019-1-2'), as.Date('2017-2-3')))

....

#Result
> monthly.df_Fin
           val      match value
2017-02-03   4       <NA>    NA
2018-12-14   1 2018-12-14    14
2019-01-02   2 2019-01-02    33
```