# find missing data from another list (between two dates)

Tags: r, data.table

Update: the first one is solved.  The issue was caused by df2 because df2 is not a data.frame.

I have two tricky situations for my data (all data frames are huge).

1) df looks like:

```
ISO3     CurrencyCode        OriginalPrice 
USA            USD                   2.5
USA            n/a                   3.6
CAN            CAD                   2.8
...
```

and df2 is a currency code list looks like

```
ISO3      CurrencyCode
USA              USD
CAN              CAD
JAP              JPY
...
```

I tried to find those missing currency codes in df by using df2.

I tried the following code but not working:

```
setDT(df)[df2, CurrencyCode:= CurrencyCode, on = .(ISO3)]
```

Another issue is similar but more complex.

df looks like:

```
ID     PayDate        CurrencyCode   ISO3
1      2016/05/01      EUR            FIN
2      2019/01/14      CAD            CAN
...
10000  2015/07/31      USD            USA
10001  2018/12/07      CAD            CAN
```

df2 looks like:

```
StartDate     EndDate      CurrencyCode   Rate      ISO3
2015/01/01    2015/03/05     CAD          0.75      CAN
2017/05/08    2017/12/31     JPY          0.0091    JAP
....

2019/07/01    2019/08/31     JPY          0.0093    JAP
```

I want to make df looks like:

```
ID     PayDate        CurrencyCode   Rate    ISO3
1      2016/05/01      EUR           1.06    FIN
2      2019/01/14      CAD           0.85    CAN
...
10000  2015/07/31      USD           1       USA
10001  2018/12/07      CAD           0.75    CAN
```

and the rate is decided by the `PayDate`.  The `PayDate` should locate between the `StartDate` and `EndDate` in df2.  If there's no enough information from df2, then the rate should be defined by the `StartDate` closet to the `PayDate`.

This is my code:

```
setDT(df)[df2, Rate:= Rate, .(date =seq(StartDate, EndDate, by = "day")), by = .(ISO3)]
```

and again.... I got error.

Comment: Can you sshow a small reprodducible example with `dput`.  There are some issues in the code.  You. are doing a `join` without `on` and second, the assignment and expansion is happening on the same code, which would have a conflict because the assignment does create or update values in the original dataset, while expansion increases the number of rows and creates a totally new dataset

Comment: If you do join with `ISO3`, make sure that at least one of the dataset have no duplicate elements for ISO3

Comment: Both df2 are unique.  No duplicate rows.

Comment: the first df2, ISO3 is unique.  However, the second one is now. Because the currency rates are varied by dates. In this case, which column should I use as an anchor? So confused.

Comment: the first code error says: `logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.`

Comment: @akrun, I fix the first issue. It's because df2 is not a data.table. I load df2 from an excel sheet directly.  After using `df2 = data.frame(df2)`, problem solved!!!  Now only the second one confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer to the first 'problem'

```
library( data.table )

#or setDT(df);setDT(df2)

df <- fread("ISO3     CurrencyCode        OriginalPrice 
USA            USD                   2.5
USA            n/a                   3.6
CAN            CAD                   2.8")

df2 <- fread("ISO3      CurrencyCode
USA              USD
CAN              CAD
JAP              JPY")

#update join DF by reference with the CurrencyCode from df2
df[ df2, CurrencyCode := i.CurrencyCode, on = .(ISO3) ]
#    ISO3 CurrencyCode OriginalPrice
# 1:  USA          USD           2.5
# 2:  USA          USD           3.6
# 3:  CAN          CAD           2.8
```

For the second one, a non-equi join will probably do the trick. But without proper sample data, I cannot produce code. Please provide a better sample set, preferably one leading to your desired output

Comment: thank you. As I updated two hours ago, problem 1 was solved and I used the code I provided in my questions. The error was cased by df2. It seems reading data from Excel directly won't create a data.frame.  I make df2 = data.frame(df2) then problem was solved.  As for the second problem, the sample data is exactly what I probided.  I tried to use the solution from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342647/how-to-match-by-nearest-date-from-two-data-frames  However, my data frames are very large and the solution is not work.

Comment: My current solution is to use the method I found above and process the code by each currency rate.  There are about 85 countries.... I cannot figure out a better way to handle it.  Thank you again!