# setkey on a subsetted shallow copy of a dataframe break the origin

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame `orig`, which is subset and assigned to `cpy`.

```
library(data.table)

orig <- data.frame(id=letters[c(2,1,2,1)], col1=c(300,46,89,2), 
                   col2=1:4, col3=1:4)

print(orig)
# id col1 col2 col3
# b  300    1    1
# a   46    2    2
# b   89    3    3
# a    2    4    4

cpy <- orig[,c("id","col1","col2")]
```

`cpy` is a shallow copy of `orig` and references parts of `orig` (all but the omitted columns).

Because `cpy` is a subset of `orig`, it references the shared columns only and  the update by reference feature of `setDT(cpy)` does not come into play. This leaves `orig` and `cpy` in a potentially dangerous state where they only share the pointers to a subset of their columns.

```
setDT(cpy)

.Internal(inspect(orig))
.Internal(inspect(cpy))
```

If now `setkey` is applied to `cpy` its columns and therefore those columns in `orig` get sorted (here update by reference plays out). The omitted columns (`col3`) are not affected by the sorting because they are unknown in `cpy`. They then are out of sync with the rest of the object.

```
setkey(cpy,id,col1)

print(cpy)
# id col1 col2
# a    2    4
# a   46    2
# b   89    3
# b  300    1

print(orig)
# id col1 col2 col3
# a    2    4    1
# a   46    2    2
# b   89    3    3
# b  300    1    4
```

To avoid this behaviour, any action which forces a deep instead of a shallow copy while assigning `cpy` (e.g. `copy()`) breaks the reference to `orig` and thus prevents the unwanted messing up there.

Is there any way that `cpy` does not loose the reference to the object `orig` itself and its omitted columns?

Comment: Maybe file a bug with the dtplyr package so they can implement select differently: https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr If you are willing to use data.table syntax (which seems likely), just adding `%>% copy` to your pipeline should work.

Comment: Yes, it's an intended function of data.table. To avoid it, you need to make a deep copy of the data.table, not just assign it a new reference, which is what you did. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another

Comment: Welp, this is one of the newest features in R it seems called a "shallow copy". Basically, R doesn't make a copy of an object if it wasn't alternated or was alternated in way that doesn't require a full copy of the object. An easy way to check if a copy was made is to use `tracemem`. after running `tracemem(orig)`, Compare: `cpy <- orig %>% select(-1)` vs. `cpy <- orig %>% mutate(col3 = 8)`. In the first case, only a shalow copy was made. When using base R this shouldn't effect you, but because data.table is using these pointers in order to modify in place, you need to be aware of this.

Comment: Thanks @BenK, after reading this question this makes much more sense. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, after playing around with `tracemem`and `.Internal(inspect(cpy))` I noticed this doesn't have to do with `dplyr` or a related package and edited the question.

Comment: @Frank, `copy` seems exactly the intended function to prevent this, thanks!

Comment: Also, take a look at this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945392/update-by-reference-vs-shallow-copy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa