# What is the difference between self-reference and update by reference in join?

Tags: r, data.table

Can someone explain to in layman terms what is the difference between these two approachs besides order

```
A <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = 1:10)
B <- data.table(id = c("c", "d", "e"), comment = c("big", "slow", "nice"))

A <- B[A, on = .(id), mult = 'first']
format(object.size(A),units='b')
A

A <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = 1:10)
B <- data.table(id = c("c", "d", "e"), comment = c("big", "slow", "nice"))

A[, comment := B[A, on=.(id), x.comment, mult = 'first']]
A
format(object.size(A), units = 'b')
```

I use `set`functions quite often in `data.table` to update and modify data, but I couldn't understand what is the real advantage of doing it in a join. What happens internally when I join and assign to the same object? Is it the same of modify in place the original `data.table` or is it making some copy?

I already read this topic ["update by reference" vs shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945392/update-by-reference-vs-shallow-copy) and `data.table` vignettes but I'm still not understanding it.

**Edit:** I don't know if this is the way to track time of it, but looks like the second approach is a lot more faster than the first one with `10^6`repplications of table `A`

**First approach**

```
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
A <- B[A, on = .(id), mult = "first"] 856.9123 5120.108 13495.41 9702.625 18861.52 70319.84   100
```

**Second approach**

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                            expr      min       lq     mean   median
 A[, `:=`(comment, B[A, on = .(id), x.comment, mult = "first"])] 471.6508 612.1226 627.4387 625.0439
       uq      max neval
 641.7865 753.1218   100
```

If the above is right there is a huge advantage of using the second method. Is it just because the first method is making a copy after the join? How R manages this copies since I'm assigning to the same object?

Comment: the first one creates a new data.table and then assigns it back to one of the data.table. the second one joins, extracts a column and then add this to A which has some additional columns *pre-allocated*. sometimes for the 2nd one you can also update some of the rows selectively in i and changing that A to .SD. besides storage space, you might also want look at speed and peak memory usage when number of rows gets large. it really depends on your use case.

Comment: @chinsoon12 How can I check memory usage?

Comment: tbh, i have no idea how to measure it accurately. there are some packages that can do that but i read from some comments that they are not accurate

Comment: Some more thoughts on pros/cons here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313203 Re how R manages the copies, I think it creates the new table somewhere in memory and then sets the pointer for `A` towards that location.