# Check frequency of data.table value in other data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
 library(data.table)
 DT1 <- data.table(num = 1:6, group = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
 DT2 <- data.table(group = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I want to add a column `popular` to `DT2` with value `TRUE` whenever `DT2$group` is contained in `DT1$group` at least twice. So, in the example above, `DT2` should be

```
    group popular
 1:     A    TRUE
 2:     B    TRUE
 3:     C   FALSE
```

What would be an efficient way to get to this?

**Updated example:** `DT2` may actually contain more groups than `DT1`, so here's an updated example:

```
 DT1 <- data.table(num = 1:6, group = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
 DT2 <- data.table(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

And the desired output would be

```
    group popular
 1:     A    TRUE
 2:     B    TRUE
 3:     C   FALSE
 4:     D   FALSE
```

Comment: Does `DT2` always have the same unique `group` from `DT1`? If so, it's simply `DT1[, .(popular = .N >= 2L), by=group]`

Comment: Hi @Arun, no it does not; I over-simplified the example here, sorry. ``DT2`` may contain more groups than ``DT1``, in which case popular should be ``FALSE`` (as it's not contained in ``DT1$group`` at least twice).

Comment: +1 for a well-formulated question

Comment: here is the non data table way! `table(factor(DT1$group, levels = unique(DT2$group))) >= 2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd just do it this way:

```
## 1.9.4+
setkey(DT1, group)
DT1[J(DT2$group), list(popular = .N >= 2L), by = .EACHI]
#    group popular
# 1:     A    TRUE
# 2:     B    TRUE
# 3:     C   FALSE
# 4:     D   FALSE ## on the updated example
```

`data.table`'s join syntax is quite powerful, in that, while joining, you can also aggregate / select / update columns in `j`. Here we perform a join. For each row in `DT2$group`, on the corresponding matching rows in `DT1`, we compute the `j`-expression `.N >= 2L`; by specifying `by = .EACHI` (please check [1.9.4 NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md)), we compute the `j`-expression each time.

---

In `1.9.4`, `.()` has been introduced as an alias in all `i`, `j` and `by`. So you could also do:

```
DT1[.(DT2$group), .(popular = .N >= 2L), by = .EACHI]
```

When you're joining by a single character column, you can drop the `.()` / `J()` syntax altogether (for convenience). So this can be also written as:

```
DT1[DT2$group, .(popular = .N >= 2L), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: Professional data-tabler

Comment: That it is pure magic. You have to add some info for future readers

Comment: One more vote and you'll get your `data.table` gold badge tonight :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it: first count the number of times each group appears in `DT1`, then simply join `DT2` and `DT1`.

```
require(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(num = 1:6, group = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
DT2 <- data.table(group = c("A", "B", "C"))

#solution:
DT1[,num_counts:=.N,by=group] #the number of entries in this group, just count the other column
setkey(DT1, group)
setkey(DT2, group)
DT2 = DT1[DT2,mult="last"][,list(group, popular = (num_counts >= 2))]

#> DT2
#   group popular
#1:     A    TRUE
#2:     B    TRUE
#3:     C   FALSE
```

Comment: This can be simplified further by aggregating `DT1` instead of `updating` it.

Comment: i think updating is more efficient: aggregating would involve copying while updating does not require any copying