# Get frequency of data.table value in other data.table and add to current data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(id = 1:6, junk = c("T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z"),
                  type = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
DT2 <- data.table(id = 4:6, junk = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
                  type = c("B", "A", "C"))
```

That is,

```
> DT1
   id junk type
1:  1    T    A
2:  2    U    B
3:  3    V    B
4:  4    X    B
5:  5    Y    A
6:  6    Z    C

> DT2
   id junk type
1:  4    X    B
2:  5    Y    A
3:  6    Z    C
```

I would like to add a column `frequency` to `DT2` which gives the number of occurences of any given `type` in `DT1`. In other words, the result should look like this:

```
> DT2
   id junk type frequency
1:  4    X    B         3
2:  5    Y    A         2
3:  6    Z    C         1
```

(This seems somewhat related to [Check frequency of data.table value in other data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453288/), but in that case, this could be accomplished by joining in the other direction. In this case, the resulting data table should be based on `DT2`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
 DT1[,frequency:=.N,by=type]
 setkeyv(DT1, colnames(DT1)[-4])
 DT1[DT2]
 #  id junk type frequency
 #1:  4    X    B         3
 #2:  5    Y    A         2
 #3:  6    Z    C         1
```

Suppose if your `DT1` is

```
 DT1 <- data.table(id = 1:5, junk = c("T", "U", "V", "X", "Y"),
              type = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A"))
```

Using the above code, gives

```
 DT1[DT2]
 #   id junk type frequency
 #1:  4    X    B         3
 #2:  5    Y    A         2
 #3:  6    Z    C        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
   help<-DT1[,list(frequency=.N),by=type]
   setkey(help, type)
   setkey(DT2, type)
   DT2[help]
   #   type id junk frequency
   #1:    A  5    Y         2
   #2:    B  4    X         3
   #3:    C  6    Z         1
```