# Calculate multiple columns from one function and add them to data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I want to return multiple results from a function on columns of `data.frame` and add these new columns to the same `data.frame` together with other simple calculation.

For a simplified example, if I want to get both integral value and absolute error of `sin` function together with the mid points of integral intervals:

```
df <- data.frame(Lower = c(1,2,3), Upper = c(2,3,4))
setDT(df)
getIntegral <- function(l, u) {
  n <- integrate(sin, mean(l), mean(u))
  list(Value=n$value, Error=n$abs.error)
}
df[,
   c('Value', 'Error', 'Mid') := {
     n <- getIntegral(Lower, Upper)
     list(n$Value,
          n$Error,
          (Lower+Upper)/2)
   }]
df
   Lower Upper     Value        Error Mid
1:     1     2 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 1.5
2:     2     3 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 2.5
3:     3     4 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 3.5
```

I don't quite like my approach because separating names of new columns and the values assigned to them makes it hard for me to read, how can I do this task better? It's part of a long data processing chain so I don't want create temp variable outside, so I would prefer solutions using `data.table` or `dplyr` alone.

Comment: Are you saying you don't like the data.table syntax??

Comment: Do you mean something like this?? `setDT(df)[,":="(Value=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Value,
                Error=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Error,
                Mid  =(Lower+Upper)/2)]`

Comment: Or perhaps this?? `setDT(df)[,c("Value","Rrror","Mid"):= with(getIntegral(Lower,Upper),list(Value,Error,(Lower+Upper)/2))]`

Comment: @jlhoward, I would like something like `setDT(df)[,":="(Value=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Value, Error=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Error, Mid =(Lower+Upper)/2)]`, but I don't want to run `getIntegral` twice.

Comment: Then do it the first way. Alternatively, you could change your function to return a named list with all three values (Value, Error, and Mid), and then just use `setDT(df)[,getIntegral(Lower,Upper),by=list(Lower,Upper)]`

Comment: @jlhoward, this is just a simplified example, in my real use case there are many combinations of such calculations, it's too much work to create new functions for every new combination of desired outputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  RHS should be a list of values, and each element of the list gets converted to a column (and recycled if necessary).

Your function already returns a `list` (of length 1 each) and `(Lower+Upper)/2` returns a vector of 3 values (here). In order to return a list, you can use the function `c()` as follows:

```
df[, c('Value', 'Error', 'Mid') := c(getIntegral(Lower, Upper), list((Lower+Upper)/2))]
#    Lower Upper     Value        Error Mid
# 1:     1     2 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 1.5
# 2:     2     3 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 2.5
# 3:     3     4 0.5738457 6.370967e-15 3.5
```

This makes use of the fact that `c(list, list)` results in a concatenated list.

Comment: As @jlhoward put in the question comment, is it possible that I can have something like `setDT(df)[,":="(Value=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Value, Error=getIntegral(Lower,Upper)$Error, Mid =(Lower+Upper)/2)]`, without running `getIntegral` twice? I would like the names of columns and the values assigned to them nearer because I have a long list of calculation.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible.