# R group by aggregate

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

In R (which I am relatively new to) I have a data frame consists of many column and a numeric column I need to aggregate according to groups determined by another column.

```
 SessionID   Price
 '1',       '624.99'
 '1',       '697.99'
 '1',       '649.00'
 '7',       '779.00'
 '7',       '710.00'
 '7',       '2679.50'
```

I need to group by SessionID and return the Max and Min for each ONTO the original data frame e.g. :

```
 SessionID   Price     Min     Max
 '1',       '624.99'   624.99  697.99
 '1',       '697.99'   624.99  697.99
 '1',       '649.00'   624.99  697.99
 '7',       '779.00'   710.00  2679.50
 '7',       '710.00'   710.00  2679.50
 '7',       '2679.50'  710.00  2679.50
```

any ideas how to do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution using `aggregate`.

First, load the data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"SessionID   Price
'1'       '624.99'
'1'       '697.99'
'1'       '649.00'
'7'       '779.00'
'7'       '710.00'
'7'       '2679.50'", header = TRUE)
```

Then `aggregate` and `match` it back to the original `data.frame`:

```
tmp <- aggregate(Price ~ SessionID, df, function(x) c(Min = min(x), Max = max(x)))
df <- cbind(df, tmp[match(df$SessionID, tmp$SessionID), 2])
print(df)
#  SessionID   Price    Min     Max
#1         1  624.99 624.99  697.99
#2         1  697.99 624.99  697.99
#3         1  649.00 624.99  697.99
#4         7  779.00 710.00 2679.50
#5         7  710.00 710.00 2679.50
#6         7 2679.50 710.00 2679.50
```

**EDIT**: As per the comment below, you might wonder why this works. It indeed is somewhat weird. But remember that a `data.frame` just is a fancy `list`. Try to call `str(tmp)`, and you'll see that the `Price` column itself is 2 by 2 numeric matrix. It gets confusing as the `print.data.frame` knows how to handle this and so `print(tmp)` looks like there are 3 columns. Anyway, `tmp[2]` simply access the second `column`/`entry` of the `data.frame`/`list` and returns that 1 column `data.frame` while `tmp[,2]` access the second column and return the data type stored.

Comment: that seems to work - HOWEVER, I'm not sure how - because tmp returns a 2 column dataframe with the columns: session_id , price. In spight of that, the final dataframe contains 2 additional columns : Min and Max. Can you explain ?

Comment: @user3628777 I've modified the post to explain. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R:

```
df <- transform(df, Min = ave(Price, SessionID, FUN = min),
                    Max = ave(Price, SessionID, FUN = max))
df
#  SessionID   Price    Min     Max
#1         1  624.99 624.99  697.99
#2         1  697.99 624.99  697.99
#3         1  649.00 624.99  697.99
#4         7  779.00 710.00 2679.50
#5         7  710.00 710.00 2679.50
#6         7 2679.50 710.00 2679.50
```

Since your desired result is not aggregated but just the original data with two extra columns, you want to use `ave` in base R instead of `aggregate`, which you would typically use if you wanted to `aggregate` the data by SessionID. (NB: AEBilgrau shows that you could also do it with aggregate with some additional matching.)

Similarly, for dplyr, you want to use `mutate` instead of `summarise` because you dont want to aggregate/summarise the data.

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(SessionID) %>% mutate(Min = min(Price), Max = max(Price))
```

Comment: this should be marked as an answer: clear, simple, short, no extra libraries

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(SessionID=c(1,1,1,7,7,7), Price=c(624,697,649,779,710,2679))

dt[, c("Min", "Max"):=list(min(Price),max(Price)), by=SessionID]
dt
#   SessionId Price Min  Max
#1:         1   624 624  697
#2:         1   697 624  697
#3:         1   649 624  697
#4:         7   779 710 2679
#5:         7   710 710 2679
#6:         7  2679 710 2679
```

In your case if you have a data.frame `df`, just do `dt=as.data.table(df)` and use the code above.

I am curious about the benchmark of the solutions on an average data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(SessionID=rep(1:1000, each=100), Price=runif(100000, 1, 2000))
dt = as.data.table(df)

algo1 <- function() 
{
    df %>% group_by(SessionID) %>% mutate(Min = min(Price), Max = max(Price))
}

algo2 <- function()
{
    dt[, c("Min", "Max"):=list(min(Price),max(Price)), by=SessionID]
}

algo3 <- function()
{
    tmp <- aggregate(Price ~ SessionID, df, function(x) c(Min = min(x), Max = max(x)))
    cbind(df, tmp[match(df$SessionID, tmp$SessionID), 2])
}

algo4 <- function()
{
    transform(df, Min = ave(Price, SessionID, FUN = min), Max = ave(Price, SessionID, FUN = max))
}   



#> system.time(algo1())
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.00    0.19 

#> system.time(algo2())
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.00    0.01 

#> system.time(algo3())
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.77    0.01    0.78 

#> system.time(algo4())
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.01    0.03
```

Comment: Why would you bet `dplyr` solution would be faster? In fact, `dplyr` solution should be even slower because unlike `data.table`, it does *not* update by reference, thus you also need to create a copy and override the original data set using `<-` in order to mimic the exact behaviour of `data.table`s `:=` operator (everyone seem to, somewhat conveniently, forget that...)

Comment: I used primarily the column with the typo SessionId and renamed it to SessionID ;) ! And my plan was never to say that `dplyr` is faster than `data.table`, I simply would have expected something like `0.1` instead of `0.19`, that's all ...I agree with `microbenchmark`, but I can't install it at my workplace due to some restrictions :) ! I was just curious to compare different possibilities on the timing and having a rough idea!

Comment: I think we should stop these fights over every single aggregation question. I think everything is summed up pretty much nicely [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly/)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I agree that we should stop milliseconds fights over every single aggregation question, especially when they are not asking explicitly for the single most efficient way of doing it..