# Complex random sampling procedure needed in R (multiple grouping and data columns of variable lengths)

Tags: r

I have data sets that have 1 to 70 columns of data with 1 to 5 columns of ID variables. I need to group by the ID variables and then randomly sample the rows of data so that the re-sampled data set is the same length as the original data set. Below is and example `DATA` set with the desired `RESULT` table.

So I need to group_by `SITE` and `DATE` and then randomly sample a single row from `STUFF:STUFF3`. Please note how the `RESULT` table retains the order of data across the columns of `STUFF:STUFF3`. For example the first two rows in the `RESULT` table are both 2,4,8 which corresponds to row 2 in the `DATA` table.

I have code that `subsets` in a `for` loop, but I would prefer to use `dplyr`. I hope this is clear. Thanks.

```
DATA = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                  DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                  STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                  STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000),
                  STUFF3 = c(4, 8, 120, 160, 400, 800, 1200, 20000, 24000))



RESULT = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                    DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                    STUFF = c(2, 2, 30, 30, 200, 300, 300, 6000, 5000),
                    STUFF2 = c(4, 4, 60, 60, 400, 600, 600, 12000, 10000),
                    STUFF3 = c(8, 8, 120, 120, 800, 1200, 1200, 24000, 20000))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` solution. You are basically want to sample rows and extract a whole data set according to this sample. You can use `.N` in order to determine each group size and then extract a whole data set using `sample` within the `.SD` function, for example (use `set.seed` in order to reproduce exact results from `sample` calls):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, .SD[sample(.N)], by = .(SITE, DATE)]
##   SITE DATE STUFF STUFF2 STUFF3
##1:    A    1     1      2      4
##2:    A    1     2      4      8
##3:    A    2    30     60    120
##4:    A    2    40     80    160
##5:    B    3   100    200    400
##6:    B    3   300    600   1200
##7:    B    3   200    400    800
##8:    C    4  6000  12000  24000
##9:    C    4  5000  10000  20000
```

---

Alternately, If you insist on using `dplyr`, you can use `n()` and `slice` in order to achieve same effect

```
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
  group_by(SITE, DATE) %>%
  slice(sample(n()))
# Source: local data table [9 x 5]
# Groups: SITE, DATE
# 
#   SITE DATE STUFF STUFF2 STUFF3
# 1    A    1     2      4      8
# 2    A    1     1      2      4
# 3    A    2    30     60    120
# 4    A    2    40     80    160
# 5    B    3   200    400    800
# 6    B    3   100    200    400
# 7    B    3   300    600   1200
# 8    C    4  6000  12000  24000
# 9    C    4  5000  10000  20000
```

Comment: Thanks David! That is the right stuff. I have been using `dplyr` extensively to mine my data sets. Does the `data.table` package have any distinct advantages over `dplyr'?

Comment: Not a simple question to answer in comments... Luckily it was already asked and answered by its two developers, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly)

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks for the link! Take care.

Comment: @Vesuccio: For such a small dataset it's not going to matter. You should pick the method that easiest to understand.