# How to improve speed of R code by replacing complex and slow plyr steps with data.table or dplyr?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I've been learning R by searching how others have done things on Stackoverflow and as a result, I've become acquainted with plyr syntax. I have the following four plyr calls with ddply that are the rate limiting steps to my code. My data approaches the hundreds of thousands to millions of records and my code mostly flies thanks to data.table and is only limited by four rate limiting but critical plyr steps. I would like to replace these with dplyr or data.table, but I've been struggling to replicate the syntax and would appreciate any help.

```
1. mergeddf3 <- ddply(mergeddf2, .(df.activ.id, channel), summarize, spotsids = paste(mainID, collapse = ","), spotsdt = paste(DateTime, collapse = ","), spotsinfos = paste(cat, collapse = ","), effrespflags = paste(effrespflag, collapse = ","))

2. webuniq_test <- ddply(webuniq, c("df.activ.id"),summarise, strRM = paste(replicate(RMCount, "RM"), collapse = ","))

3. webactiv2 <- ddply(webactiv, .(VisitorID), summarize, VisitorPath = paste(Path, collapse = ","), RMpath = paste(strRM, collapse = ","), ConvTot=sum(Conv), Conv2Tot=sum(Conv2), Cov3Tot=sum(Conv3)) #check that nrow dec

4. MeltForSO3 <- ddply(MeltForSO2, c("VisitorID","ID"),summarise, SplitThis = paste(value, collapse = ","))
```

For (1) here is the benchmark:

```
#user  system elapsed 
#378.463   3.136 383.786
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish in these steps (they are similar):

1. They involve the aggregation of data by an ID field or ID field
2. Aggregation of granular character fields occurs with paste and
   collapse. For example, a field might be a driver's stops as he drops
   off packages where a "stops" field would have values 'a', 'b', 'c'
   for each stop. Plyr with `stops_path = paste(stops, collapse = ",")`
   will give aggregate those steps to a single line as "a,b,c"
3. Numeric data is sometimes summed up in the same aggregation step, for example `ConvTot=sum(Conv)`

I've been unsuccessful in my attempts to replicate this with either dplyr or data.table.

Is there an advantage to using one over the other for these types of aggregations? I've taken a look at this and it seems that data.table might be better for my very simple use case because of the cleaner syntax: 
[data.table vs dplyr: can one do something well the other can't or does poorly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly)

Here's my unsuccessful attempt to replicate (1) above with data.table:

```
setkey(setDT(mergeddf2),df.activ.id, MarketingChannel)
mergeddf3test <- mergeddf2[, list(spotsids = paste(mainID, collapse = ","), spotsdt = paste(DateTime, collapse = ","), spotsinfos = paste(tvcat, collapse = ","), effrespflags = paste(effrespflag, collapse = ",")), by=list(df.activ.id,Channel)]
```

This threw an error: `unused argument (by = list(df.activ.id, Channel))`I wrote that from code off I researched on SO on how to incorporate paste into data.table. I took out the by argument just to see what would happen, and got another error with the line below:

```
mergeddf3test <- mergeddf2[, list(spotsids = paste(spotID, collapse = ","), spotsdt = paste(DateTime, collapse = ","), spotsinfos = paste(tvcat, collapse = ","), effrespflags = paste(effrespflag, collapse = ","))]
```

The error was `"Error in paste(spotID, collapse = ",") : object 'spotID' not found"` which is weird because that field is definitely in the data. I thought this data.table line would properly aggregate the data with the by fields (df.activ.id and Channel) and combine the character fields as with the (a,b,c) example above.

Clearly I'll need to properly learn the syntax of either dplyr or data.table given the scale of data I'm working with so I've signed up for the data camp class for both packages. Still, I would appreciate any help on how to approach this in the immediate term.

Thanks!

Comment: When asking for help you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. If speed is an issue, be sure to include benchmarks you've performed so we can compare alternative solutions. Also, it's better to describe in words what you are trying to do rather than just asking for code to be translated from one package to another.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're right, I didn't give a reproducible sample (I normally do). I didn't because I figured that it was unnecessary since I'm just trying to figure out how to use paste and sum with another package. I do think I did a good job of explaining with words what I've tried to do and provided code for my un-successful attempts. I will update the post with the benchmarks.

Comment: The data camp classes are a great place to start. Without a reproducible example my best guess is: for some reason, `setDT` is not actually setting as a data.table. You could check with `str(mergeddf2)`. I can't imagine any other reason for `by` and column names like `spotID` not being found. Personally, I think everything before "Here's my attempt" in your question could go -- you should stick to a single programming problem on this site, as that's what works best for the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replication with `data.table` works for me (except that channel is capitalized). Below are my attempts to replicate the first step of your list with `dplyr` and with `data.table`.

```
# required packages
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
```

#### sample data

```
mergeddf2 <- data.frame(df.activ.id = 1:5, 
                        channel = 1:8, 
                        mainID = 1:40, 
                        DateTime = Sys.Date() - 80:1, 
                        cat = letters[1:6], 
                        effrespflag = rnorm(240), 
                        othervar = 1, 
                        MarketingChannel = 2)
```

#### plyr solution

```
mergeddf3 <- ddply(mergeddf2, .(df.activ.id, channel), summarize, 
                   spotsids = paste(mainID, collapse = ","), 
                   spotsdt = paste(DateTime, collapse = ","), 
                   spotsinfos = paste(cat, collapse = ","), 
                   effrespflags = paste(effrespflag, collapse = ","))
```

#### dplyr solution

```
mergeddf3.dplyr <- 
  mergeddf2 %>% 
  group_by(df.activ.id, channel) %>%
  summarise_each(funs = funs(paste(., collapse = ",")), mainID, DateTime, cat, effrespflag) %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("df.activ.id", "channel", "spotsids", "spotsdt", "spotsinfos", "effrespflags")) 
# check for equality
all.equal(mergeddf3, as.data.frame(mergeddf3.dplyr))
## [1] TRUE
```

#### data.table solution

```
setDT(mergeddf2)
mergeddf3test <- mergeddf2[, list(spotsids = paste(mainID, collapse = ","), 
                                  spotsdt = paste(DateTime, collapse = ","), 
                                  spotsinfos = paste(cat, collapse = ","), 
                                  effrespflags = paste(effrespflag, collapse = ",")),
                           by=list(df.activ.id,channel)] 
# check for equality
all.equal(mergeddf3, setDF(setkeyv(mergeddf3test, c("df.activ.id", "channel"))))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Another data.table variant might be `mergeddf2[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","), by=list(df.activ.id,channel), .SDcols = c("mainID", "DateTime", "cat", "effrespflag")]` although you'd still need to set the correct variable names afterwards

Comment: Thank you for an exhaustive solution! My original data.table attempt worked for me too after I restarted R (in frustration) and  ran the setDT step on its own. Not sure where I was screwing up? Again, my lack of understanding of how the package works probably is the root reason why I couldn't get it to work. The data.table solution is 6x faster and I'm going to try with dplyr. I will post bench marks for both packages when I do.

Comment: Here are the performance benchmarks: plyr (original code): `383.786`  data.table `49.922` dplyr: `40.154`

Comment: Just wanted to add: I re-ran data.table (same machine) and got faster times: `# RUN 2: user  system elapsed 
# RUN 2: 40.327   0.359  41.184 ` I know why. The previous step converted a data.table into a data.frame so I could use it with plyr. Since I'm continuing on with data.table, I didn't have to use the setDT step which I believe saved 9 seconds. Would love to know the internal workings of the code there!