# How to merge two tables with 'holes' in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have data from three different experimental conditions, in two different modes, and I have computed and stored in a first data.frame the mean and sd for each condition for each mode. It looks like

```
t1 <- data.frame(condition = rep(c("A","B","C"),times=2),
             mode = rep(c(1,2),each=3),
             mean = rnorm(6),
             sd = rnorm(6))
```

I then have computed for each pairwise comparison of conditions the mann-whitney rank-sum tests. The resulting data.frame looks like this:

```
t2 <- data.frame(mode = rep(c(1,2),each=3),
             test = rep(c("AvB","AvC","BvC"),2),
             pvalue = runif(6,0,0.2)
             )
```

I would like to combine the two data.frames in a single data.frame with 'holes', that ofr each test shows the mode, the means of the conidtions actually tested, and the p-value.
I have in mind something like this:

```
mode    mean A  mean B  mean C  test    pvalue
1       1.34    1.12            A v B   0.067
1       1.34            0.98    A v C   0.021
1               1.12    0.98    B v C   0.345
```

I know that the resulting table has holes in it -- not so good for running stats on it -- but my aim is to create a .tex table (using xtable()) to show all the possible pairwise tests, and, at the same time, display the mean of the variable in each condition in each mode. This is for display in a paper appendix.

Thanks!

Comment: In your `t1` dataframe, one of the `rep` calls needs `times` instead of `each` (otherwise you don't get unique identifiers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without plyr or dplyr using reshape2. It can handle more conditions and tests and does not require hardcoding comparisons.

```
library(reshape2)
#make column with variables that are tested (so can be used if many pairs/changing
#names as long as there is a clear separation
t2$var1 <- gsub("v.+","",t2$test)
t2$var2 <- gsub(".+v","",t2$test)

#combine data in long format
t3 <- merge(t1,t2,by="mode")

#create mean_na vector with removed means when test is not performed
t3$mean_na <- with(t3, ifelse(condition==var1|condition==var2,mean,NA))

#cast to table
res_temp <- dcast(mode+test~condition,value.var="mean_na",data=t3)
res_temp

#re-add pvalue
result_final <- merge(res_temp,t2[,c("mode","test","pvalue")],by=c("mode","test"))

> result_final
  mode test           A          B        C     pvalue
1    1  AvB -0.56047565 -0.2301775       NA 0.13114116
2    1  AvC -0.56047565         NA 1.558708 0.14170609
3    1  BvC          NA -0.2301775 1.558708 0.10881320
4    2  AvB  0.07050839  0.1292877       NA 0.11882840
5    2  AvC  0.07050839         NA 1.715065 0.05783195
6    2  BvC          NA  0.1292877 1.715065 0.02942273
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

t2 %>% 
  separate(test, into = c("cond1", "cond2"), sep = "v", remove = FALSE) %>%
  gather(key, condition, -mode, -pvalue, -test) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  left_join(t1 %>% select(-sd)) %>% 
  spread(condition, mean) %>%
  setNames(c(names(.)[1:3], paste("mean", names(.)[4:6])))
```

Which gives:

```
#  mode test      pvalue     mean A    mean B     mean C
#1    1  AvB 0.053444134 -0.6264538 0.1836433         NA
#2    1  AvC 0.077222819 -0.6264538        NA -0.8356286
#3    1  BvC 0.002678067         NA 0.1836433 -0.8356286
#4    2  AvB 0.076477591  1.5952808 0.3295078         NA
#5    2  AvC 0.173938169  1.5952808        NA -0.8204684
#6    2  BvC 0.068069799         NA 0.3295078 -0.8204684
```

If you want to pass the result into an xtable you could add:

`... %>% xtable() %>% print(type = "html")`

```html
<!-- html table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
<!-- Fri Jun 19 18:45:36 2015 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> mode </th> <th> test </th> <th> pvalue </th> <th> mean A </th> <th> mean B </th> <th> mean C </th>  </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 1 </td> <td align="right"> 1.00 </td> <td> AvB </td> <td align="right"> 0.05 </td> <td align="right"> -0.63 </td> <td align="right"> 0.18 </td> <td align="right">  </td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 2 </td> <td align="right"> 1.00 </td> <td> AvC </td> <td align="right"> 0.08 </td> <td align="right"> -0.63 </td> <td align="right">  </td> <td align="right"> -0.84 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 3 </td> <td align="right"> 1.00 </td> <td> BvC </td> <td align="right"> 0.00 </td> <td align="right">  </td> <td align="right"> 0.18 </td> <td align="right"> -0.84 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 4 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td> AvB </td> <td align="right"> 0.08 </td> <td align="right"> 1.60 </td> <td align="right"> 0.33 </td> <td align="right">  </td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 5 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td> AvC </td> <td align="right"> 0.17 </td> <td align="right"> 1.60 </td> <td align="right">  </td> <td align="right"> -0.82 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="right"> 6 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> <td> BvC </td> <td align="right"> 0.07 </td> <td align="right">  </td> <td align="right"> 0.33 </td> <td align="right"> -0.82 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)

t1 <- data.frame(condition = rep(c("A","B","C"),times=2),
                 mode = rep(c(1,2),each=3),
                 mean = rnorm(6),
                 sd = rnorm(6))

t2 <- data.frame(mode = rep(c(1,2),each=3),
                 test = rep(c("AvB","AvC","BvC"),2),
                 pvalue = runif(6,0,0.2))
```

Comment: this is good and does the trick but I am not (yet) familiar with dplyr right now... I am more at ease with the reshape2 answer above. Which poses the next question, that is: should I learn dplyr and switch over to it? is it worth the effort? thanks!

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto Lots of very knowledgeable fellows on SO use `data.table`. I myself prefer `dplyr`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly

Answer (score 0):

This will work for a fairly small size of data; if you actually have a lot more conditions, this approach will not be fun:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

means <- dcast(t1, mode~condition, value.var='mean')

results <- merge(t2, means) %>%
    # extract conditions of each test row
    mutate(first=substr(test,1,1), second=substr(test,3,3), 
           # replace untested condition means with ""
              meanA=ifelse(first=='A'|second=='A', A, ""),
              meanB=ifelse(first=='B'|second=='B', B, ""),
              meanC=ifelse(first=='C'|second=='C', C, "")) %>%
    # discard unwanted columns
    select(mode, meanA, meanB, meanC, test, pvalue)

> print(results)
  mode  meanA  meanB meanC test     pvalue
1    1 -0.646 -0.778        AvB 0.03597074
2    1 -0.646        0.014  AvC 0.11394383
3    1        -0.778 0.014  BvC 0.14393726
4    2  0.083  0.275        AvB 0.16493966
5    2  0.083        0.619  AvC 0.06548713
6    2         0.275 0.619  BvC 0.08474118
```

Comment: good solution, but you have guessed right: I indeed have more conditions, that was only a smallish example.

Comment: right; Heroka's answer handles multiple conditions nicely