# Efficiently finding the count of column values for distinct rows in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, count, subset, memory-efficient

Suppose I have a data frame as:

```
id   value
1    "hi"
1    "hi"
1    "hi again"
1    "hi again"
2    "hello"
2    "hi"
```

Now I want to get the count of each *value* for each of the distinct values in id column. The output would be like

```
id    value       Freq
1     "hi"        2
1     "hi again"  2
2     "hello"     1
2     "hi"        1
```

I tried splitting up the first data frame for each distinct *id* and get the frequency using the *table()* function on the *value* column and appending the *id* column later. Also, I end up with a lot of dataframes in my memory. I just want to know if I can achieve the above dataframe without chewing up my memory with lot of dataframes(as I have almost 5 million rows).

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(DF))` Use `table` on both columns. Alternately, use `data.table` (which will prove more efficient) as below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your data.frame is called df, using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .(Freq = .N), by = .(id, value)]
```

using dplyr:

```
libary(dplyr)
group_by(df, id, value) %>% summarise(Freq = n())
```

You should choose one of those two packages (dplyr or data.table) and learn it really thoroughly. In the long run you will likely use both. But beginning with one and really understanding it will help you tremendously. I use both pretty much everytime I use R.

dplyr tends to be easier for beginners, so I would read a [tutorial](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) on it. This will help you forever. There is also a great video-tutorial which can be found on [this site](http://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/archives/) under The grammar and graphics of datascience.

I personally prefer data.table because it is faster and more flexible. Check the new HTML vignettes and the PDF vignettes [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Thank you @grrgrrbla for great explanation and the resources.  I tried using dplyr and somehow I haven't achieved the result I needed.

Comment: glad it helped, please accept the answer if it helped by clicking the arrow and upvote it

Comment: By the way, these two approaches run at the same speed if you use dplyr syntax on a data.table. (I just tried it on my computer.) `DT <- data.table(id=1:1e6)[,.(value=sample(letters,sample(5,1))),by=id]; DF <- setDF(copy(DT)); system.time(group_by(DT, id, value) %>% mutate(Freq = n())); system.time(DT[ , .(Freq = .N), by = .(id, value)])` Working with a data.frame is 5x slower, though: `system.time(group_by(DF, id, value) %>% mutate(Freq = n()))`

Comment: interesting and strange at the same time

Comment: By "dplyr syntax with a data.table", I mean `group_by(DT,...)` where DT is a data.table. The author of dplyr, hadley, likes to point out that dplyr can be fast when using data.table as a "backend" in this way.

Comment: I didnt know that, do you know why? and where can I find more information on this

Comment: Sure, here's where I saw him mention it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840349/1191259 The other answers there are also worth reading.