# How to analysis large data (larger than my available RAM size) with data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm learning `R` and I'm a big fan of `data.table` package - I like it's database-like syntax and performance.

When I was reading web pages and blogs on data analysis, I found this post:

> A Large Data Workflow with Pandas
>
> Data Analysis of 8.2 Million Rows with Python and SQLite
>
> https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/big-data-analytics-with-pandas-and-sqlite/

I would like to practice this data analysis with `data.table`; however, there's only 4Gb RAM on my laptop:

```
➜  ~  free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3686         966        1976         130         743        2359
Swap:          8551           0        8551
➜  ~
```

The dataset is a 3.9Gb CSV file, my availalbe memory is not enough to read the file as a `data.table`. But I'm not willing to give up `data.table` package.

Question:

1. Is there a database interface for `data.table` package? I searched its documentation and have no good luck.
2. If `data.table` is not the right tool for this task, which approach is highly recommended?

   (1) `sqldf` or (2) `sqlite` + `dplyr` or (3) `ff`/`bigmemory` package?

I've noticed that each of above packages has distinctive syntax. The `pandas` in the linked post can do almost all these task in one set of tools. Is there possibly a similar approach in R?

Comment: I don't think there is a database interface for `data.table`, but `dplyr` has one. Though it depends on what exactly are you trying to do. You can potentially load the data in chunks and work on each chunk at a time for example. Take a look at both answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly)

Comment: @eddi Good point. I do plan to upgrade my computer. It support at most `4 Gb x 2` RAM. I currently have `2 Gb x 2`. So I have to give away these old RAM and buy two new one. Maybe next year, `8 Gb` is not enough, maybe I should buy a new computer.