# Dplyr code is slower than expected when creating new variables with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` to create three new variables on my data frame. The data frame is 84,253 obs. of 164 variables. Below is my code.

```
# ptm <- proc.time()
 D04_Base2 <- D04_Base %>% 
    mutate(
        birthyr = year(as.Date(BIRTHDT,"%m/%d/%Y")),
        age = (snapshotDt - as.Date(BIRTHDT,"%m/%d/%Y")) / 365.25,
        age = ifelse(age > 100, NA, age)
        )
# proc.time() - ptm
user  system elapsed 
12.34    0.03   12.42
```

However, I am wondering if there is a noticeable issue with my code as it is taking much longer than I expected to run or is this something else. As displayed above, it is taking about 12 seconds for the code to complete.

Comment: would be faster if you made BIRTHDT into a Date just once

Comment: Also, I tested creating the variables using Base R and the results were much faster. After all my research it seemed dplyr should be faster than Base and hence the question.

Comment: What was the equivalent base R code that you compared this against? You really should include some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can run it ourselves to compare.

Comment: Yeah, you should just store dates as Date from the beginning. No point doing any analysis with a date-as-string. Also, `system.time({commands})` is a more reliable way to do timings, I've been told.

Comment: Adding a column is a very simple task, and one base R does quite well at. It is a little dated now, but [this blog post](http://datascience.la/dplyr-and-a-very-basic-benchmark/) suggests that for simply adding a new column `dplyr` is comparable with `base`. `dplyr` will do better than base especially in joins and grouped operations.

Comment: Did you try to use the equivalent package: `data.table` check this   [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial). Some benchmarks consider it has better performance than `dplyr` package (see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) for a discussion about it). Also consider using `setDT` from the same package it allows to change the input by reference (no copy), that would provide you a much better performance. Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are some inefficiencies in your code:

1. You convert the `BIRTHDT` column to `Date` twice. (This is by far the biggest issue.)
2. `base::as.Date` isn't super fast
3. You can use `dplyr::if_else` instead of `base::ifelse` for a little bit of performance gain.

Let's do some tests:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mbm = microbenchmark::microbenchmark

# generate big-ish sample data
n = 1e5
dates = seq.Date(from = Sys.Date(), length.out = n, by = "day")
raw_dates = format(dates, "%m/%d/%Y")
df = data.frame(x = 1:n)
```

#### Date conversion

```
mbm(
    mdy = mdy(raw_dates),
    base = as.Date(raw_dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   mdy 21.39190 27.97036 37.35768 29.50610 31.44242 197.2258   100  a 
#  base 86.75255 92.30122 99.34004 96.78687 99.90462 262.6260   100   b
```

Looks like `lubridate::mdy` is 2-3x faster than `as.Date` at this particular date conversion.

#### Extracting year

```
mbm(
    year = year(dates),
    format = format(dates, "%Y")
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    year 29.10152 31.71873 44.84572 33.48525 40.17116 478.8377   100  a 
#  format 77.16788 81.14211 96.42225 83.54550 88.11994 242.7808   100   b
```

Similarly, `lubridate::year` (which you already seem to be using) is about 2x faster than `base::format` for extracting the year.

#### Adding a column:

```
mbm(
    base_dollar = {dd = df; dd$y = 1},
    base_bracket = {dd = df; dd[["y"]] = 1},
    mutate = {dd = mutate(df, y = 1)},
    mutate_pipe = {dd = df %>% mutate(y = 1)},
    times = 100L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   base_dollar 114.834 129.1715 372.8024 146.2275 408.4255 3315.964   100 a  
#  base_bracket 118.585 139.6550 332.1661 156.3530 255.2860 3126.967   100 a  
#        mutate 420.515 466.8320 673.9109 554.4960 745.7175 2821.070   100  b 
#   mutate_pipe 522.402 600.6325 852.2037 715.1110 906.4700 3319.950   100   c
```

Here we see base do very well. But also notice that these times are in **microseconds** whereas the above times for the date stuff were in **milliseconds**. Whether you use `base` or `dplyr` to add a column, it's about 1% of the time used to do the date conversions.

#### ifelse

```
x = rnorm(1e5)
mbm(
    base_na = ifelse(x > 0, NA, x),
    base_na_real = ifelse(x > 0, NA_real_, x),
    base_replace = replace(x, x > 0, NA_real_),
    dplyr = if_else(x > 0, NA_real_, x),
    units = "ms"
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#       base_na 9.399593 13.399255 18.502441 14.734466 15.998573 138.33834   100  bc
#  base_na_real 8.785988 12.638971 22.885304 14.075802 16.980263 132.18165   100   c
#  base_replace 0.748265  1.136756  2.292686  1.384161  1.802833   9.05869   100 a  
#         dplyr 5.141753  6.875031 14.157227 10.095069 11.561044 124.99218   100  b
```

Here the timing is still in milliseconds, but the difference between `ifelse` and `dplyr::if_else` isn't so extreme. `dplyr::if_else` requires that the return vectors are the same type, so we have to specify the `NA_real_` for it to work with the numeric output. At Frank's suggestion I threw in `base::replace` with `NA_real_` too, and it is about 10x faster. The lesson here, I think, is "use the simplest function that works".

---

In summary, `dplyr` is slower than `base` at adding a column, but both are super fast compared to everything else that's going on. So it doesn't much matter which column-adding method you use. You can speed up your code by not repeating calculations and by using faster versions of bigger operations. Using what we learned, a more efficient version of your code would be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
D04_Base2 <- D04_Base %>% 
    mutate(
        birthdate = mdy(BIRTHDT),
        birthyr = year(birthdate),
        age = (snapshotDt - birthdate) / 365.25,
        age = replace(age > 100, NA_real_)
    )
```

We can ballpark the speed gain on 1e5 rows at about 180 milliseconds as broken out below.

- 170 ms (single `lubridate::mdy` at 30 ms instead of two `as.Date` calls at 100 ms each)
- 10 ms (`replace` rather than `ifelse`)

The *adding a column* benchmark suggests that we could save about 0.1 ms by not using the pipe. Since we are adding multiple columns, it's probably more efficient to use `dplyr` than to add them individually with `$<-`, but for a single column we could save about 0.5 ms by not using `dplyr`. Since we've already sped up by 180-ish ms, the potential fraction of a millisecond gained by not using `mutate` is a rounding error, not an efficiency boost.

In this case, the most complicated thing you're doing is the `Date` conversion, but even this *is likely not your bottleneck* if you're doing more processing. To optimize your code you should see which pieces are slow, and work on the slow bits. [This is called *profiling*.](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) In this answer I used `microbenchmark` to compare competing short methods head-to-head, but other tools (like the `lineprof` package) are better for identifying the slowest parts of a block of code.

Comment: Regarding their ifelse, I was thinking `replace(age, age > 100, NA_real_)` looked like a better choice. Dunno how that fares in benchmarks, though.

Comment: Good thought - I put it in. Turns out it doesn't matter: median is lower but mean is higher in my 100 trials.

Comment: @Frank better thought - I had not read your comment well. *Now* I went back and used `replace` and it is 10x faster than `if_else`.