# How to rename selected columns using dplyr with new column names as strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4)), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", 
"Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

That looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
*        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4
```

What I want to do is to replace `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Length` with appended string `to_app <- ".xxx"` resulting in:

```
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
          5.1         3.5          1.4
          4.9         3.0          1.4
          4.7         3.2          1.3
          4.6         3.1          1.5
          5.0         3.6          1.4
```

I tried this with error:

```
df %>% rename(paste(Sepal.Length,to_app,sep="") = Petal.Length,paste(Sepal.Width,to_app,sep="") = Petal.Length)
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in "df %>% rename(paste(Sepal.Length,to_app,sep="") ="

Comment: Just another R construction of doing this, using `match` - `vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"); names(df)[match(vars, names(df))] <- paste0(vars, to_app)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use dplyr's `rename` function, it would be best to create a named vector / list and call it using the `.dots` argument in the standard evaluation version:

```
cols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
to_app <- ".xxx"
cols <- setNames(cols, paste0(cols, to_app))

df %>% rename_(.dots = cols)

## A tibble: 5 × 3
#  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
#*            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#1              5.1         3.5              1.4
#2              4.9         3.0              1.4
#3              4.7         3.2              1.3
#4              4.6         3.1              1.5
#5              5.0         3.6              1.4
```

Note however, that this approach is subject to change with the next version 0.6.0 of dplyr (see e.g. http://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/13/dplyr-0-6-0-coming-soon/ and http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `rename_at()` function for this (starting in *dplyr_0.7.0*) or `rename_with()` (starting in *dplyr_1.0.0*).

For example, you can pass the variables you want to rename as strings.  In your example, the `paste0` function can be used to append on the appropriate suffix to each column.

```
cols = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
to_app = ".xxx"
```

For *dplyr_1.0.0*, use `rename_with()`.  The function argument comes before the column argument.  You can use the tidy-select function `all_of()` (or others) to choose columns.

```
rename_with(df, .fn = ~paste0(., to_app), .cols = all_of(cols) )

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
*            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
1              5.1         3.5              1.4
2              4.9         3                1.4
3              4.7         3.2              1.3
4              4.6         3.1              1.5
5              5           3.6              1.4
```

Earlier versions of *dplyr* use `rename_at()`.  This has been superseded in version 1.0.0, which means there are new functions to use as above but this particular function is not going away.

```
rename_at(df, cols, list( ~paste0(., to_app) ) )

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
*            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
1              5.1         3.5              1.4
2              4.9         3.0              1.4
3              4.7         3.2              1.3
4              4.6         3.1              1.5
5              5.0         3.6              1.4
```

You can also use the select helper functions to choose variables for renaming, such as `contains`.

```
rename_at(df, vars( contains("Length") ), list( ~paste0(., ".xxx") ) )

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
*            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
1              5.1         3.5              1.4
2              4.9         3.0              1.4
3              4.7         3.2              1.3
4              4.6         3.1              1.5
5              5.0         3.6              1.4
```

This `list()` coding replaces the previous `funs()` coding starting in *dplyr_0.7.0*.  Previously, e.g., `funs( paste0(., to_app) )`

Comment: Just updating for dplyr 0.8, rename_at(df, cols, list(~paste0(., to_app) ) )

Comment: dplyr 1.0.0 (and using stringr::str_c),  rename_with( .data = df, .fn = ~ str_c(., to_app), .cols = contains("Length") ). Other rename_x functions have been superseded.

Answer (score 25):

**EDIT:** these days, I'd recommend using `dplyr::rename_with`, as per [@aosmith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044471/3246758). Write a function that takes your old column names as input and returns your new column names as output, and you're done :)

I'm a little late to the party on this, but after staring at the [programming vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for a long time, I found the relevant example in the [Different input and output variable](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-input-and-output-variable)
.

In my simpler use case, I just needed to rename a column to the value of a string:

```
> df1 = data_frame(index = 1:5, value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
> df1
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  index value
  <int> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    20
3     3    30
4     4    40
5     5    50

> newname = 'blau'
> newname2 = 'wheee'

> df1 %>% rename(!!newname := value, !!newname2 := index)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  wheee  blau
  <int> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    20
3     3    30
4     4    40
5     5    50
```

So if you're happy to do that manually, you can just:

```
df %>%
  rename(!!paste("Sepal.Length", "xxx", sep = ".") := Sepal.Length)
```

If, however, you need something that automatically appends `".xxx"` to *whatever column name is supplied to it*, I recommend you have a close look at that section. It's still a bit over my head, unfortunately, but I can see that it's doable >_>

Answer (score 5):

```
df %>% setNames(paste0(names(.), to.app))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width.xxx Petal.Length.xxx
*            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
1              5.1             3.5              1.4
2              4.9             3.0              1.4
3              4.7             3.2              1.3
4              4.6             3.1              1.5
5              5.0             3.6              1.4
```

EDIT:

Apologies for not reading properly. Here's a solution with data.table package.

```
var <- names(df)[c(1,3)]
df %>% setnames(., var, paste0(var, to.app))
df

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
*            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
1              5.1         3.5              1.4
2              4.9         3.0              1.4
3              4.7         3.2              1.3
4              4.6         3.1              1.5
5              5.0         3.6              1.4
```

Comment: I don't want all columns but selected ones (Sepal.Length and Petal.Length) please see my OP again.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the aim is to rename all columns that contain "Length":

```
colnames(df) <- ifelse(grepl("Length", colnames(df)), 
                       paste0(colnames(df), to_app), 
                       colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

The best I can do in the development version of `dplyr` (to be released on May 11th):

```
cols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
to_app <- ".xxx"
ns <- paste0(cols, to_app)

rename(df, 
       !!ns[1] := !!as.name(cols[1]), 
       !!ns[2] := !!as.name(cols[2]))
```

To do this fully programatically, one needs to use `quos` instead:

```
xx <- do.call(quos, setNames(map(cols, as.name), ns))
rename(df, !!!xx)
```

Both give:

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 3
>   Sepal.Length.xxx Sepal.Width Petal.Length.xxx
> *            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
> 1              5.1         3.5              1.4
> 2              4.9         3.0              1.4
> 3              4.7         3.2              1.3
> 4              4.6         3.1              1.5
> 5              5.0         3.6              1.4
> ```

One liner:

```
rename(df, !!!do.call(quos, setNames(map(cols, as.name), paste0(cols, to_app))))
```

Comment: The question then is, how would this be done without calling each column separately? I think it might be something with `!!!` instead of `!!`

Comment: Yes, I've added _a_ solution for that, but not sure if there is a way to avoid `do.call` and/or `setNames` there.

Comment: Good to see this example, but I hope that will not be the final version of doing since imho, it's too complicated for a rather simple column renaming

Comment: I agree! Some things have become nicer, but I don't readily see a convenient way of doing this with `tidyeval`/`rlang`. I wouldn't say it's terrible though. Maybe @hadley can give us his take on this.

Comment: [tongue-in-cheek] and to think that Hadley once argued that in data.table one needs to learn ["*cryptic shorcuts*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly#comment32357862_21435339)... Not to mention that that `:=` thingi looks somewhat familiar from some cryptic package out there which I fail to recall its name....

Comment: @docendodiscimus For what it's worth, I don't think the final version will change much since package maintainers have already be notified of the upcoming release.