# How to rename a column to a variable name "in a tidyverse way"

Tags: r, dplyr

I've created a simple data frame:

```
    date      ticker     value
------------------------------
  2016-06-30  A2M.ASX   0.0686
  2016-07-29  A2M.ASX  -0.0134
  2016-08-31  A2M.ASX  -0.0650
  2016-09-30  A2M.ASX   0.0145
  2016-10-31  A2M.ASX   0.3600
  2016-11-30  A2M.ASX  -0.1429
```

I want to change the `value` column's name to whatever is in my `metric` variable name, and I want to do it using dplyr.

My sample data:

```
df = structure(list(date = c("2016-06-30", "2016-07-29", "2016-08-31", "2016-09-30", "2016-10-31", "2016-11-30"), ticker = c("A2M.ASX", "A2M.ASX", "A2M.ASX", "A2M.ASX", "A2M.ASX", "A2M.ASX"), value = c(0.0686, -0.0134, -0.065, 0.0145, 0.36, -0.1429)), .Names = c("date", "ticker", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
metric = "next_return"
```

I know how to do it in one line:

```
colnames(df)[3] = metric
```

But I want do it in a tidyverse way so I can use it in a pipe.  I've been tinkering with `replace_` but I only manage to get errors:

```
> dplyr::rename_(df, "ticker" = metric)
Error: `next_ret_1M` contains unknown variables
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With the newest dplyr (>0.7.0) you would use

```
rename(df, !!metric:=value)
```

The syntax is "new_name=old_name" and you need to use `:=` with `!!` to put a variable on the left side of a parameter name.

Comment: How would you do that if `metric` and `value` represent several columns?

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf It depends on exaclty what's stored in those values. some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504509/2372064 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487773/how-to-rename-selected-columns-using-dplyr-with-new-column-names-as-strings

Answer (score 1):

### Update dplyr >1.0.0

```
df %>% rename_with(~metric, value)
```

#### Explanation:

The rename can be performed in a pipe with the `rename_with` which is more generic and thus more powerful. This function in the easiest form would just return a value of a variable, here metric, as an anonymous function, i.e. `function(x) return metric`. The latter can be expressed in shortform with `~ metric`.

This syntax is more powerful because it would equally work if use several names stored in the variable.