# Rename within dplyr chain to wrap a feature header

Tags: r

```
> x <- data.frame(
+   blah = 1:10
+ ) %>% 
+   mutate(`two words` = rnorm(10, 0, 1))
> x
   blah   two words
1     1  0.73446160
2     2  0.75684241
3     3  0.02717962
4     4 -1.12091171
5     5 -1.26650625
6     6  0.20336003
7     7 -0.56643766
8     8 -0.17442082
9     9 -0.85714736
10   10  0.49964362
```

I'd like to wrap `two words heading onto two lines`.

Tried:

```
> x <- data.frame(
+   blah = 1:10
+ ) %>% 
+   mutate(`two words` = rnorm(10, 0, 1)) %>% 
+   rename(str_wrap(`two words`, width = 15) = `two words`)
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  mutate(`two words` = rnorm(10, 0, 1)) %>% 
  rename(str_wrap(`two words`, width = 15) ="
```

How can I rename a header with a space in order to wrap the text?

Comment: I think you want to use this method with `!!` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973165/496803 - something like: `rename(!!str_wrap("two words", width = 15) := \`two words\`)`

Comment: Alternately, you can use `rename_at(vars(\`two words\`), str_wrap, 15)`.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand what you mean by `two words heading onto two lines`. can you show your expected output?

Comment: The comments above worked for me if you either of you want to make them an answer. @RonakShah I just mean test wrap so when the table is printed out the table headings are text wrapped