# How to find the mean of certain values in a large dataframe using loop

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
         Female.ID    Mate.ID  relatedness
    1           A1         C1       0.0000
    2           A1         D1       0.0000 
    3           A1         E1       0.5062
    4           A1         F1           NA
    5           B1         G1       0.0425
    6           B1         H1       0.0000
    7           B1         I1       0.0349
    8           B1         J1       0.0000
    9           B1         K1       0.0000
    10          B1         L1       0.0887
    11          B1         M1       0.1106
    12          B1         N1       0.0000
```

I want to create a new dataframe and find the mean relatedness of all the mates for female.ID A1 and the mean relatedness for all the mates of female.ID
B1, etc.

I want something like this:

```
    Female.ID    mean.relatedness
           A1              0.1687
           B1              0.0346
```

This dataframe is much bigger than this example one, which is why I'm not just subsetting for the female one by one and finding the mean relatedness. I was thinking of doing some kind of for loop, but I'm not sure how to start it off.

Comment: You can probably just group, and use `dplyr` to calculate mean. How do you want to handle your NA values. Should they be implicitly zero, or excluded all together?

Comment: I think excluding might be best. Thanks for your help! Looks like crazybilly excluded NA in his code, so I will that out.

Comment: @akrun you're right, sorry, the mean relatedness value in the first row of my desired dataframe was incorrect. I just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: For more references, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-mean-per-group-mean-by-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

themeans  <- df %>%
    group_by(Female.ID) %>%
    summarize(mean.relatedness = mean(relatedness, na.rm = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

- to do a group by "Female.ID"
- then summarize using the **mean** while ignoring the NA.

If the data is too large you may need to use a faster package like **data.table** (which is a fast package with a simple syntax). for more details please take a look at this link [data.table vs dplyr: can one do something well the other can't or does poorly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly)

In general looping is not optimized in R. It can be kept as a final solution only if the treatment can't be supported by the package.

Here the syntax using data.table (df being the initial data.frame)

```
library(data.table)

dt<- as.data.table(df)
dt1 <- dt[, .(mean.relatedness= mean(relatedness, na.rm = TRUE)),
            by="Female.ID"]
>dt1
 Female.ID mean.relatedness
1:        A1        0.1687333
2:        B1        0.0345875
```

note that the grouping-by can be done over a multi-variables vector, the summarizing function can be other than the mean, and **na.rm = TRUE** is needed to ignore the NA while summarizing.