# How to filter two separate csv files and return an output?

Tags: r, dplyr

So, I am very new to R. So might be a silly question. I have an assignment I need to do. The idea is, I have two `csv` files, i.e. Contributions and Candidates. The first is the amount of donations made to a candidate and the second is the candidate information including party.

My task is to filter only the Candidates whose party are "R" and then find the  average of donations made to "R".

I thought of using the `dplyr` package for this task.

The first idea I had was to split this into two i.e, capture the candidates whose party are "R" and store them in a data frame. I encountered an error though

> no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('mts', 'ts')"

```
df_donations <- select(filter(dataread_candidates,dataread_candidates$party  =="R"))
dataread_candidates <- read.csv("candidates.csv", header = TRUE)
dataread_contributions <- read.csv("contributions.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Is there any way I can do this in a single line or do I need to split it like I initially thought of doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Donations <- fread("CANDIDATE_NAME  DONATIONS
Trump   100
Sanders 1000
Hillary 890
Lincoln 1500
Bush    600")



Candidates <- fread("CANDIDATE_NAME PARTY
Trump   R
Sanders D
Hillary D
Lincoln R
Bush    R")


Donations %>% inner_join(Candidates, by = "CANDIDATE_NAME") %>%
group_by(PARTY) %>% summarise(AverageDonations = mean(DONATIONS)) %>% filter(PARTY == "R")

 PARTY AverageDonations
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 R                 733.
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, although, it was a little tricky for me to convert it into my code since I was using the wrong Filter (From Stats Package), rather than the Dplyr one.

Answer (score -1):

This will be really general without an example of your data's structure. If you use the `data.table` package you could follow the concept below and be able to use `fread()` instead of `read.csv()` (helps if you have 10,000+ donors).

**Code concept**

```r
dt[ , mean(`Donation`, na.rm = TRUE), by = `party`]
```

If you [provide an example dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can help you better. With `data.table` it might be possible to have the merge on the same line.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants to get his results using `dplyr`

Comment: The OP did mention dplyr but also asked to do it in one line so I focused on that part. I learned a lot [from a discussion on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly?rq=1) about `data.table` versus `dplyr`.