# How to Divide DataFrame into groups in R

Tags: r, large-data

I have a large data frame like this :

df:

```
col_1   col_2  col_3
  1       2       1
```

and I want to divide it to this subgroups very fast:

df_1:

```
 col_1   col_3
  1       1
```

df_2:

```
  col_2
    2
```

I know there is a way with which and is like this:

```
df_1 <- df[df == 1]
df_2 <- df[df == 2]
```

but it's not fast. 
what should i do ?

thanks

Comment: Do you have only one row in your data? If not can you include few more rows and show expected output based on that?

Comment: I have just one row @RonakShah

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
 df %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key,val) %>% 
  group_split(val)   #attributed to @agila for pointing out the unnenecessary call to group_by that I missed initially
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  key     val
  <chr> <int>
1 col_1     1
2 col_3     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  key     val
  <chr> <int>
1 col_2     2

attr(,"ptype")
```

Comment: I think t should be something like  `df %>% gather(key, val) %>% group_split(val) `

Comment: Still doesn't achieve OP's desired output at least on my machine.

Comment: @agila Fixed it(or so I think). It seems OP is more interested in grouping by val rather than key which on second look is what you wrote there and I missed. Corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

I'd suggest looking at the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages, which are focused on fast and memory efficient implementations. Especially i'd suggest the amazing answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly?rq=1), which will give an good understanding of what these two packages are capable of.

`data.table` does tend to outperform `dplyr` as the number of groups and repeated subsets grow, as it utilizes indexed and keyed subsets, but for most it comes down to a preference. Focusing on subsetting I'll provide a reproducible example and some speed comparisons.

### Reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(LETTERS, 1e7, TRUE), 
                 random_numbers = rnorm(1e7), 
                 random_binaries = rbinom(1e7, 1, 0.3))
# size = 152.6 MiB
format(object.size(df), units = "MiB")
```

### Methods:

#### Base-R methods

Now in base-R subsetting can be performed in a myriad ways, one is the one you have shown yourself. `df[df == ..]`. An alternative is to use the `subset` function, however this a utility function, and is focused on readability rather than speed, and will usually perform worse. An example of their use is given below. However one may use the `which` function, to convert a logical vector into indices, and doing this may improve performance.

```
df[df$group == "C",]
#Equivalent
df[which(df$group == "C"),]
#Equivalent
subset(df, group == "C")
```

#### dplyr methods

An alternative is the dplyr package. The dplyr is syntax sugar, giving piping options not unlike a few other packages (for example the [`magrittr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package), but different benchmarks (shown in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly?rq=1)) show that this package can be used to improve performance on various aspects. However i am no expert on this package, as i tend to use the `data.table` package. The package provides the `%>%` piping function and some utility functions such as `filter` which can be used for subsetting data

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(group == "C")
# subsetting two columns
df %>% filter(group == "C", random_binaries == TRUE) #Equivalent to group == "C" & random_binaries == TRUE
```

#### Data.table methods:

Last another popular package is the [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) package. This package is designed for performance and memory efficiency, like `dplyr`. The syntax is designed to be similar to SQL statements, (select, from, where, group by), but starting out the syntax can be a bit confusing. The package provides a new `data.table` class, to be used rather than the `data.frame` class, which is notoriously slow for subsetting.

However, one can almost completely ignore the syntax of the package, as the `data.table` utilizes the `data.frame` syntax in most cases, and can be used as a `data.frame` in every circumstance.

```
library(data.table)
#Convert the data.frame to data.table
setDT(df)
```

The data.table has two standard methods: Using **indices** and using **keys**. **Indices** are used if one uses similar methods to the `data.frame` methods:

```
df1 <- df[random_binaries == TRUE]
df2 <- df[group == "C"]
```

Indices has roughly the same speed on **the first usage** but will increase on performance on **every subsequent** use.

**Keys** are used to pre-sort the `data.table`, which allows for smart subsetting. Setting the key does take some time, and has a slightly different syntax, but outperforms other methods (although indices are similar in speed)

```
#Set the key using either setkey, or setkeyv (multiple columns)
setkeyv(df, c("group", "random_binaries"))
#Subset on group
df[.("C")]
#subset on random_binaries
df[CJ(group, TRUE, unique = TRUE)]
df[.(unique(group), TRUE)]
# Subset on multiple conditions
df[.(c("C", "H"), c(TRUE, TRUE))]
```

The syntax may be confusing, but one can check out their useful [wiki page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki), or the many [stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+data.table) (8968 as of today), which provide answers to most questions.

#### Performance comparison

I've checked the performance of the subsetting methods presented, which are visualized below. The visualization, shows the various methods for a subset of `group == "C"` and `group == "H" & random_binaries == TRUE"` using the methods illustrated. The x-axis indicates the run time in milliseconds, and the y-axis shows the methods.
The widths of the blobs indicates the range, while the size of the blot illustrates the density of times in a range.

From the visualization one can see, that for a dataset of 2 columns, subsetting on both 1 and 2 columns, the `data.table` method using keys are much much faster (marked as `data.table_.._keyed`), while using indexes slightly outperforms the remaining methods. Using `subset` is slower than standard methods, and suprisingly for this illustration `dplyr` is slower than base-R, however this is might be due to my inexperience with the package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `lapply` from base R which gives you a list of your desired dataframes -

```
df <- data.frame(col_1 = 1, col_2 = 2, col_3 = 1)

lapply(unique(unlist(df)), function(x) {
  df[, df == x, drop = F]
})

# output

[[1]]
  col_1 col_3
1     1     1

[[2]]
  col_2
1     2
```