# R Why dplyr counts unique values (n_distinct) by groups faster than data.table (uniqueN)?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

As I understand, data.table is more efficient and faster than dplyr but I found the opposite situation today in my job. I created a simulation to explain the situation.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

library(microbenchmark)

#  data simulated
dt = data.table(A = sample(1:4247,10000, replace = T),
                B = sample(1:119,10000,replace = T),
                C = sample(1:6,10000,replace = T),
                D = sample(1:30,10000,replace = T))

dt[,ID:=paste(A, ":::" , 
              D,":::",
              C)]
# execution time

microbenchmark(
  DATA_TABLE = dt[, .(count=uniqueN(ID)), 
                  by=c("A","B","C")
                  ],
  DPLYR      = dt %>% 
               group_by(A,B,C)  %>% 
               summarise(count = n_distinct(ID)),
  times = 10
              )
```

## Results

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr         min          lq        mean      median    uq         max        neval
 DATA_TABLE 14241.57361 14305.67026 15585.80472 14651.16402  16244.22477 21367.56866  10
      DPLYR    35.95123    37.63894    47.62637    48.56598  53.59919    62.63978     10
```

You can see the big difference! Does someone know the reason? Do you have some advice about when use dplyr or data.table?

I have my full code in data.table syntax now I don't know if I need to translate some chunks of code to dplyr due to this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread probably has everything you need to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot for sharing! I will read it

Comment: I ran your code and data.table was about 30 times *faster* than dplyr on my machine.

Comment: I can (somewhat) reproduce `data.table`-slower on my machine, R-3.5.3, dplyr-0.8.3, data.table-1.12.8.

Comment: @eipi10 maybe a versions thing? I got dplyr ~75x faster with R 3.5.2, dplyr-0.8.3, data.table-1.12.6

Comment: @eipi10 to be honest, I'm really confused because last week I had that situation for the same code (data.table faster than dplyr) but in this week I faced that issue (dplyr faster). So, I thought I was doing something wrong. I will check the other packages I have in my full R project to check if a new I added masks some functionalities of data.table. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GregorThomas, maybe so. I'm running R 3.6.2, dplyr-0.8.99.9000, data.table-1.12.8.

Comment: The difference is almost entirely `uniqueN` vs `n_distinct`.

Comment: Even replacing `uniqueN` with `length(distinct())` makes the methods fairly comparable. So I think the real question is *why is `uniqueN(ID)` so slow here, even compared to `length(unique(ID))`?*

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3739, *"uniqueN() is very slow compared to length(unique())"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
dt[order(A, B, C), {
        uniqn <- rleidv(c(.SD, .(ID)))
        lastidx <- c(which(diff(rowidv(.SD))<1L), .N)
        c(.SD[lastidx], .(count=c(uniqn[lastidx[1L]], diff(uniqn[lastidx]))))
    }, .SDcols=cols]
```

timing code:

```
cols <- c("A","B","C")
microbenchmark(times=1L,

  DATA_TABLE = a00 <- dt[, .(count=uniqueN(ID)), cols],

  DATA_TABLE1 = a01 <- dt[, .(count=length(unique(ID))), cols],

  DPLYR      = a_dplyr <- dt %>%
    group_by(A,B,C)  %>%
    summarise(count = n_distinct(ID)),

  #https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120#issuecomment-463584656
  mtd0 = a10 <- unique(dt, by=c(cols, "ID"))[, .(count=.N), cols],

  #https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120#issuecomment-463597107
  mtd1 = a11 <- dt[, .N, c(cols, "ID")][, .(count=.N), cols],

  mtd2 = a2 <- dt[order(A, B, C), {
    uniqn <- rleidv(c(.SD, .(ID)))
    lastidx <- c(which(diff(rowidv(.SD))<1L), .N)
    c(.SD[lastidx], .(count=c(uniqn[lastidx[1L]], diff(uniqn[lastidx]))))
  }, .SDcols=cols]
)
```

checks:

```
> fsetequal(a00, a01)
[1] TRUE

> fsetequal(a00, setDT(a_dplyr))
[1] TRUE

> fsetequal(a00, a10)
[1] TRUE

> fsetequal(a00, a11)
[1] TRUE

> fsetequal(a00, a2)
[1] TRUE
```

timings for the particular dataset below:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  DATA_TABLE 147478.1089 147478.1089 147478.1089 147478.1089 147478.1089 147478.1089     1
 DATA_TABLE1   4998.8236   4998.8236   4998.8236   4998.8236   4998.8236   4998.8236     1
       DPLYR 244081.6925 244081.6925 244081.6925 244081.6925 244081.6925 244081.6925     1
        mtd0   4519.4046   4519.4046   4519.4046   4519.4046   4519.4046   4519.4046     1
        mtd1   2866.5808   2866.5808   2866.5808   2866.5808   2866.5808   2866.5808     1
        mtd2    809.7442    809.7442    809.7442    809.7442    809.7442    809.7442     1
```

data with 1mio rows:

```
#R-3.6.1 64bit Win10
library(data.table)  #data.table_1.12.8 getDTthreads()==4
library(dplyr)  #dplyr_1.0.0
library(microbenchmark)

#  data simulated
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6
dt = data.table(A = sample(1:424700,nr, replace = T),
  B = sample(1:11900,nr, replace = T),
  C = sample(1:600, nr, replace = T),
  D = sample(1:3000, nr, replace = T))
dt[,ID:=paste(A,":::",D,":::",C)]
```

Comment: This should be used by default in data.table instead of uniqueN.

Comment: @skan it depends on the dataset. Applying unique before uniqueN might be faster. Sometimes applying count twice might also be faster