# R - Weighted sum

Tags: r, weighted

I have a dataframe with multiple asnwers from a sort of census.
I want to summ the number of people that actually lives in certain places, and to do so i need to calculate a weighted variable too - I can't just sum all the number of people that the table shows.

```
  ZONA   ID_DOM   FE_DOM NO_MORAD
1    1 00010001 15.41667        2
2    1 00010001 15.41667        2
3    1 00010001 15.41667        2
4    1 00010001 15.41667        2
5    1 00010001 15.41667        2
6    1 00010002 15.41667        4
```

Saying it again, I want to get the sum of `NO_Morad` by `ZONA`, counting only once each of the `ID_DOM`. All that weighted by `FE_DOM`.

to just count the number of `ID_DOM`s I used

```
Zona <- count(OD_2017[!duplicated(OD_2017$ID_DOM),], wt = FE_DOM, Zonas=ZONA, name = "N_domicilios")
```

but now i don't know how to do so. I was trying something like

```
Zona <- OD_2017 %>%
  group_by(ZONA) %>%
  summarise(ID_DOM = n_distinct(ID_DOM), weights(FE_DOM))
```

but it didnt worked out.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: it'd be something like 
Zona 1 - 92
...
Zona X - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see pipes in your attempts, but here is one approach using data.table.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ZONA = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ID_DOM = c("00010001", 
"00010001", "00010001", "00010001", "00010001", "00010002"), FE_DOM = c(15.41667, 15.41667, 
15.41667, 15.41667, 15.41667, 15.41667), NO_MORAD = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**Code:**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[,unique(.SD)[,.(WeightedSum = sum(FE_DOM * NO_MORAD))],by="ZONA"]
```

**Output:**

```
   ZONA WeightedSum
1:    1    92.50002
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks!

Any way, would u know how to do that using pipes?
I guess data table is a bit slower, am i right?

Comment: I use data.table because it is faster in many of my use cases on very large datasets. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/) for how others view the pros and cons of each.