# what is the relationship between the R packages `labelled` and `sjlabelled`?

Tags: r, dplyr, package

The R packages [`labelled`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/labelled/index.html) and [`sjlabelled`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjlabelled/index.html) have highly similar descriptions, and I am trying to determine the relationship between the two and whether one does something the other cannot or does poorly. I suspect `labelled` may be a fork of `sjlabelled` since the author of the latter is listed among credits for the former. However, both have been updated within the last month, and I haven't yet found documentation which addresses the relationship between the packages, if any.

It doesn't look like either is formally part of the tidyverse family (I'd consider that to be a meaningful endorsement), but the logo and cheatsheet on the `labelled` [github page](https://larmarange.github.io/labelled/) suggest it may aspire to be.

From what I can tell, the "sj" in `sjlabelled` appears to stand for a nickname of the author, rather than a distinguishing feature of the package. I'm aware the same author is responsible for other "sj..." packages as well.

Comment: I voted to close this because I feel it can either be heavily opinion-based (even if you aren't asking for opinions, just the facts), and is dangerously close to asking us to recommend packages. It's a tweener on both accounts, I admit. I encourage you to reach out to either of the authors, as one may have significant insight towards motivation, technical differences, setc.

Comment: @r2evans This thread is very similar in form to [this extremely popular thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) which also solicits comparisons between two packages (I even borrowed some of the language). Responses there included evidence and examples beyond subjective judgements, and led to a very informative discussion. Correspondence with the authors does not replace this discussion. I'd encourage you to reconsider your vote to close, unless rules have changed since that thread was posted.

Comment: Good points. Perhaps that one survived better because (a) it was 6.5 years ago, and (b) it was and is at the center of a polarizing discussion about dialects in R. While that second point clearly violates one of my arguments, it also was a very "frequent" debate back then (still is now, to a certain degree) because of the dialects and package-ecosystems presented. Perhaps I was hasty to VTC. (I don't have any input or an answer for you, unfortunately. Good luck!)