# Filter list of data.tables by function argument

Tags: r, list, data.table

I'm writing on a function that should filter each `data.table` in a list.

An Example:

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

My.List <- 
  as.data.table(iris) %>% 
  split(by = "Species")

map(My.List, ~.x[Sepal.Length < 5.5])
```

That is exactly what I want my result to be. But the function should be very user friendly. This is my desired function and it was even better if I could have multiple conditions separated by a `,`, like in `dplyr`'s `filter`:

```
myfunction(My.List, Sepal.Length < 5.5)
myfunction(My.List, Sepal.Length < 5.5, Petal.Width > 1)
```

Comment: Just trying to learn and understand. I tried `as.data.table(iris) %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(Sepal.Length < 5.5, Petal.Width > 1) `, but you want to create your own function, to filter rows? Is there a reason to not use dplyr? maybe I misunderstood your needs. Thank you

Comment: In my real use case it isn't a grouped data.frame, it's a list with separate data.frames (and this has to be). And I want one function that is really easy to use for my clients and it does more than just filtering but filtering is a part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this is called Non Standard Evaluation `nse`. For the tidyverse, you could check [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for the NSE implementation

Anyway to answer your question:

```
library(tidyverse)
myfunction <- function(lst, ...){
  nms <- enquos(...)
  map(lst, ~filter(.x, !!!nms))
}

myfunction(My.List, Sepal.Length < 5.5)
myfunction(My.List, Sepal.Length < 5.5, Petal.Width > 1)
```

If interested in ONLY BASE R functions, you could do:

```
myfunction <- function(lst, ...){
  nms <- substitute(list(...))
  lapply(lst, function(x)x[Reduce("&", eval(nms, x)),])
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I like to combine data.table and especially tidyverse's pipe. There is a nice discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly in which the combination of data.table and the pipe is discussed, too. Usually I don't use filter, I use the i-component of data.table. I like data.table for its syntax, too.

Comment: "The purpose of datatable is for speed" is opinion based. I believe many people would continue using it even though it was not the fastest option because of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, that's the best solution! If you have a data.table you don't even need the very last comma.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R equivalent that also does the trick. It uses `match.call` to extract the expressions (if there are any), then uses `lapply` to iterate through the list, evaluating each expression in the context of each data frame in the list using `eval`. This produces a list of logical vectors for each data frame, which are then combined into a single vector with an "&" via `Reduce`. This subsets each data frame.

```r
myfunction <- function(.list, ...)
{
  mc <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  if(length(mc) == 1) return(.list)
  lapply(.list, function(df)
  {
    conds <- lapply(mc[-1], function(condition) eval(condition, envir = df))
    df[Reduce("&", conds),]
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain this a little bit, please?