# Year over Year in R by a certain category

Tags: r

The data frame has three columns:

```
year = c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002)   
sales = c(100,104,106,108,112,115,121, 143) 
category = c("Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal")  
df = data.frame(year, sales, category)
```

I used the below code to find year over year growth by category but the output adds a new column that doesn't have correct values of the growth or decline percentage. Maybe this is because my code is not accounting for different categories. Any idea on how to do that in R? In SQL you could group by but I tried adding that in the above code in R and that gave me a new column with 0 in all rows?!

`setDT(df)[, new.col := Sales/shift(Sales) - 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to **group by category** in `setDT(df)[, new.col := Sales/shift(Sales) - 1]`.

You can do as follows (using data.table syntax):

```r
library(data.table)

year <- c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002)   
sales <- c(100, 104, 106, 108, 112, 115, 121, 143) 
category <- c("Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal")  
dt <- data.table(year, sales, category)
dt[, growth_rate := sales / shift(sales) - 1, by = category]
```

Also note that :

- you can use the constructor `data.table` directly (as I did) instead of using `data.frame` followed by `setDT`
- The data.table that you built is already sorted on the year. If it was not the case, you would add the instruction `setorder(dt, year)` before computing the year over year growth rate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use `data.table`, which I am not too familiar with, but here is how you would do it, using the library `tidyverse`.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) for some discussion on the pros and cons of both libraries.
You forgot to add the year vector in your example, so I made one up.

```
library(tidyverse)

sales = c(100,104,106,108,112,115,121, 143) 
category = c("Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal", "Joint", "Auto", "Personal")  
year <- c('2018','2018','2018','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020')
df = data.frame(year, sales, category)

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(growth_percentage = sales/lag(sales,n = 1, order_by = year))
```