# How to create a table showing the biggest values in a large csv file in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a very big csv file and im trying to find the amount of times a value has been repeated in a column.
csv file im using: https://www.kaggle.com/nyphil/perf-history

this is what ive been trying to do.

```
library(dplyr)
repeatedcomposers<-table(ny_philarmonic$composerName)
```

this works but only gives me 1000 values instead of the 2767 composers in the dataframe.
I also need it to create a separate dataframe so i can use it later.

Comment: Try `ny_philarmonic %>% count(composerName)`

Answer (score 0):

The main `dplyr` verbs (e.g., `mutate()`, `arrange()`, etc) always return dataframes. So if you are looking to do some kind of operation that results in an operation, you are correct that a `dplyr`-centric approach is probably a good place to start. Base R functions are often vector-centric, so something like `table()` will often require additional steps afterward, if you want a dataframe in the end.

Once you've committed to `dplyr`, You have at least two options for this particular dilemma:

### Option 1

The `count()` function gets you there in one step.

```
df %>% 
  count(composerName) %>%
  arrange(-n) # to bring the highest count to the top
```

### Option 2

Although it is one more line, I personally prefer the more verbose option because it helps me see what is happening more easily.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(composerName) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(-n) # to bring the highest count to the top
```

It has the added benefit that I can role right into additional `summarize()` commands that I might care about too.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(composerName) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(), 
    n_sq = n^2) # a little silly here, but often convenient in other contexts
```

### Consider data.table for large datasets

EDIT: I would be remiss if I failed to mention the `data.table` might be worth looking into for this larger dataset. Although `dplyr` is optimized for readibility, it often slows down with datasets with more than 100k rows. In contrast, the `data.table` package is designed for speed with large datasets. If you are an R-focused person who often runs into large datasets, it's worth the time to look into. [Here is a good comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly)