# Points within buffer with the same id

Tags: r, pandas, buffer, geopandas

I have a buffer layer and a point layer:

```
 buffer_gdf
     ID
0    1A
1    1B
2    1C
```

and

```
 point_gdf
      ID
0     1A
1     1A
2     1A
3     1A
4     1A
5     1B
6     1B
7     1B
8     1B
9     1B
10    1B
11    1B
12    1B
13    1B
14    1C    
15    1C
16    1C
17    1C    
18    1C
19    1C
20    1C    
21    1C
22    1C
```

Is there a way to count how many points with ID=1A are within buffer ID=1A, how many points ID=1B are within buffer ID=1B, how many points ID=1C are within buffer ID=1C, and so on...
I have more than 20000 buffers and more than 300000 points.

I'm using pandas but I can also use R.

**Sorry, I didn't mention that some points are outside the buffers. I just need those within the buffers**

Comment: is `point_gdf['ID'].value_counts()` what you are looking for?

Comment: @rhug123 no, because there are some points that are outside the buffers :(

Comment: `buffer_gdf.join(point_gdf['ID'].value_counts(),on='ID',rsuffix = 'count'_)` should work, but I havent tested it.

Comment: Are you open to `data.table` in R?  If so, I have a powerful one-liner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476119): `buffer_gdf[point_gdf, on = .(ID), nomatch = 0][, .N, by = ID]`, where the datasets are `data.table`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all so much for your help. However, the best and useful answer for me is  [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272933/spatial-join-based-on-attribute-join).

Answer (score 3):

Here, is one way in `R`

```
sapply(buffer_gdf$ID, function(x) sum(point_gdf$ID == x))
1A 1B 1C 
 5  9  9
```

Or with `outer`

```
rowSums(outer(buffer_gdf$ID, point_gdf$ID, `==`))
[1] 5 9 9
```

---

If this should not consider `buffer_gdf`, `table` would be enough

```
table(point_gdf$ID)
```

Or do a `subset` and then get the `table`

```
with(point_gdf, table(ID[ID %in% buffer_gdf$ID]))
```

#### data

```
buffer_gdf <- structure(list(ID = c("1A", "1B", "1C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2"))

point_gdf <- structure(list(ID = c("1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1B", "1B", 
"1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", 
"1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Get your value counts using:

```py
counts = point_gdf.value_counts()
```

Then `reset_index` and merge your `buffer_gdf` on `counts` to attach your sums: `buffer_gdf.merge(counts.reset_index(), on='ID', how='left', validate='1:1')`.<sup>1</sup>

You could write this as a one-liner:

```py
buffer_gdf.merge(point_gdf.value_counts().reset_index(), on='ID',
                 how='left', validate='1:1')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You don't *need* to specify `validate='1:1'`. I just almost always provide a validate keyword when writing merges to ensure that the data are formatted how I expect them. I think it's a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with the [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718317) of `data.table` and the elegance of `INNER JOIN`.

## Solution

Given your sample data, reproduced here as `data.table`s

```
buffer_gdf <- structure(list(ID = c("1A", "1B", "1C")),
                        row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table"))


point_gdf <- structure(list(ID = c("1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C", "1C")),
                       row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("data.table"))
```

the following approach

```
library(data.table)


# ...
# Code to generate 'buffer_gdf' and 'point_gdf' as data.tables.
# ...


#         |----------- INNER JOIN -----------||--- Count ---|
buffer_gdf[point_gdf, on = .(ID), nomatch = 0][, .N, by = ID]
```

should yield output like this:

```
   ID N
1: 1A 5
2: 1B 9
3: 1C 9
```

## Note

If your datasets are not already `data.table`s, use `as.data.table()` to convert them prior to the operations.

If you want, you can customize the header when counting: `[, .(Count_Name = .N), by = ID]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `join` the tables and get the `count` by `groups`. Below is the code.

```
point_gdf %>% inner_join(buffer_gdf , by = "ID") %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: I like this elegant concept, but will `dplyr` stand up to the sheer volume of data?  Perhaps `data.table` would provide better performance...

Comment: @Greg well frankly, if performance is what you're looking for, i wouldn't rely on R

Comment: @ifly6 Do you have any benchmarks where pandas vs collapse vs data.table?