# More efficient way of using group_by > mutate > slice

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame("Month" = c("April","April","May","May","June","June","June"),
"ID" = c(11, 11, 12, 10, 11, 11, 11),
"Region" = c("East", "West", "North", "East", "North" ,"East", "West"),
"Qty" = c(120, 110, 110, 110, 100, 90, 70),
"Sales" = c(1000, 1100, 900, 1000, 1000, 800, 650),
"Leads" = c(10, 12, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4))

Month   ID     Region    Qty    Sales   Leads
April   11     East      120    1000    10
April   11     West      110    1100    12
May     12     North     110    900     9
May     10     East      110    1000    8
June    11     North     100    1000    6
June    11     East      90     800     5
June    11     West      70     650     4
```

I want a dataframe that looks like this

```
Month   ID     Qty     Sales   Leads   Region
April   11     230     2100    22      East
May     12     110     900     9       North
May     10     110     1000    8       East
June    11     260     2450    15      North
```

I am using a the following code

```
result <- df %>% group_by(Month, ID) %>% mutate(across(.cols = Qty:Leads, ~sum(.x, na.rm = T))) %>% slice(n = 1) 

result$Region <- NULL
```

I have over 2 million such rows and it is taking forever to calculate the aggregate.

I am using mutate and slice instead of summarize because the df is arranged in a certain way and I want to retain the Region in that first row.

However I think there could be a more efficient way. Please help on both. Can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Your code cannot create your expected output. I can see you want to retain a certain order, but I don't understand why you cannot do it by arrange the data frame after summarize.

Comment: You said you used this code `df %>% group_by(month, ID) %>% mutate(across(.cols = Qty:Leads, ~sum(.x, na.rm = T))) %>% slice(n = 1) ` (Notice that `month` should be `Month`) to generate the expected outcome. But the results from this is the same using `summarize`. The order is changed in both approaches using `mutate` or `summarize`. So I don't understand why you cannot use `summarize`. You have to arrange the data frame anyway.

Comment: Furthermore, you delete the `Region` column deliberately in your code with `result$Region <- NULL`, but your expected outcome contains that column. I just don't understand what you did and what is your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`summarize` makes more sense to me than `mutate` and `slice`. This should save you some time.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>%
  group_by(Month, ID) %>%
  summarize(across(.cols = Qty:Leads, ~sum(.x, na.rm = T)),
            Region = first(Region))
result
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
# # Groups:   Month [3]
#   Month    ID   Qty Sales Leads Region
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 April    11   230  2100    22 East  
# 2 June     11   260  2450    15 North 
# 3 May      10   110  1000     8 East  
# 4 May      12   110   900     9 North
```

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

cols <- c("Qty", "Sales", "Leads")

df[, c(lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE),
       Region = first(Region)), .SDcols = cols, 
   by = .(Month, ID)][]
#    Month ID Qty Sales Leads Region
# 1: April 11 230  2100    22   East
# 2:   May 12 110   900     9  North
# 3:   May 10 110  1000     8   East
# 4:  June 11 260  2450    15  North
```

Comment: My bad. I edited my question. I have given a reason why I used mutate and slice and I will have to retain the 'Region' column

Comment: @FinRC I have updated my answer to keep the `Region` column. I still think `summarize` is the right way. If you need to maintain a certain order, arrange the data frame after summarize.

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. Is there a data.table solution? As data.frame it is taking very long again.

Comment: Beware that the result is a grouped tibble - you might want to add `ungroup()` at the end

Comment: @FinRC I have updated my answer with a `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 3):

We can apply generic speed-up strategies:

1. Do less
2. Choose an appropriate back-end
3. Use appropriate data structures

`dplyr` provides syntactic sugar for data manipulation, but may not be the most efficient when it comes to handling large data sets.

#### solution 1

We could rewrite the code slightly to be more efficient by using the `collapse` package, which provides a C++ interface to `dplyr` functions. It prepends `dplyr` functions with `f`, with one exception `fsubset` which is similar to `dplyr::filter` (or base R `subset`).

```
library(collapse)
df |>
    fgroup_by(Month, ID) |>
    fsummarise(Qty = fsum(Qty),
               Sales = fsum(Sales),
               Leads = fsum(Leads),
               Region = fsubset(Region, 1L),
               keep.group_vars = T) |>
    as_tibble() # optional
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   Month    ID   Qty Sales Leads Region
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 April    11   230  2100    22 East  
#> 2 June     11   260  2450    15 North 
#> 3 May      10   110  1000     8 East  
#> 4 May      12   110   900     9 North
```

Where `|>` (Requires R version > 3.5) is a slightly faster pipe than `%>%`. Its result is *ungrouped*.

#### solution 2

`data.table` is often lauded for its [speed, memory use and utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly). The easiest conversion from existing `dplyr` code to use `data.table` is using the `dtplyr` package, which ships with `tidyverse`. We can convert it by adding two lines of code.

```
library(dtplyr)
df1 <- lazy_dt(df)
df1 %>%
      group_by(Month, ID) %>%
      summarize(across(.cols = Qty:Leads, ~sum(.x, na.rm = T)),
                Region = first(Region)) %>%
      as_tibble() # or data.table()
```

Note that this results is an *ungrouped* data.frame at the end.

#### Benchmarks

Approaches are put in wrapper functions. `dplyr` here is www's approach. All approaches outputting is a *tibble*.

```
bench::mark(collapse = collapse(df), dplyr = dplyr(df), dtplyr = dtplyr(df),
            time_unit = "ms", iterations = 200)[c(1, 3,5,7)]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  expression median mem_alloc n_itr
  <bch:expr>  <dbl> <bch:byt> <int>
1 collapse    0.316        0B   200
2 dplyr       5.42     8.73KB   195
3 dtplyr      6.67   120.21KB   196
```

We can see that `collapse` is more memory efficient, and significantly faster compared to `dplyr`. `dtplyr` approach is included here, as its *time complexity* is different than that of `dplyr` and its convenience to rewrite.

Per @www's request, an inclusion of pure `data.table` approach, wrapper functions rewritten for brevity. Input/ Output is a `data.frame` for `collapse` and a `data.table` for `data.table` respectively.

```
data.table = \(x){setDT(x); cols = c("Qty", "Sales", "Leads");x[, c(lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T), Region = first(Region)), .SDcols = cols, by = .(Month, ID)][]}
# retainig the `|>` pipes for readability, impact is ~4us. 
collapse = \(x) x|>fgroup_by(Month, ID)|>fsummarise(Qty = fsum(Qty),Sales = fsum(Sales),Leads = fsum(Leads),Region = fsubset(Region, 1L),keep.group_vars = T)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
bench::mark(collapse(df), iterations = 10e3)[c(1,3,5,7)] ; bench::mark(data.table(dt), iterations = 10e3)[c(1,3,5,7)]
  expression     median mem_alloc n_itr
  <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int>
1 collapse(df)    150us        0B  9988
2 data.table(dt)  796us     146KB  9939
```

The difference between `collapse` and pure `data.table`, for such a small dataset, is negligible. The reason for speed increase is likely the use of `fsum` instead of base R `sum`.

Comment: Thank you for providing this nice answer with comparison on several methods. If you don't mind and if you have time, could you add my `data.table` solution to your bench mark comparisons? Just curious if pure `data.table` solution could be more efficient.

Comment: @www pure `data.table` is likely a very efficient solution for OP, in my experience `collapse` and `data.table` are quite close in performance. But its tough to make a fair comparison as `setDT` overwrites the `data.frame`, so it doesn't incur the same data structure conversion cost every iteration of the benchmark, and also has slightly different output. Further, small sample data wont give the whole picture (i reckon DT is faster for 2M rows). What do you reckon is fair, to include `as_tibble` or give all approaches their native I/O formats?