# Is there an R function to rearrange the columns and the rows?

Tags: r

```r
data_path <- structure(
  list(
    V1 = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A3GALT2"),
    Week25_DF16_10 = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1000 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1001 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1002 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = c("data.table","data.frame")
)
```

The datapath is my data structured in a way that all of the Week25... are in the column, and the genes are in the row. I want to rearrange it in a way like the second picture I have, in which all of the Week25... are on the row. Note that this is a very large dataset, so the rows to column function may not work. Any helps or suggestions would be appreciated very much

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How many rows and columns in your dataset?

Comment: @LTyrone there are 32,580 rows and 63,498 columns in my dataset

Comment: @Mark sorry as I don't know about that, I will make sure this not happen again

Comment: I also tried the transpose function but it couldn't run

Comment: You can use something like `dput(data_path[1:5,!:5])` and copy the result into a codeblock in your question to share your data. You can also do this for your example output. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really helpful information regarding how to create a good question. Good luck!

Comment: @Greg I tried your function but my R was aborted while I run the function :(

Comment: While 2^31 - 1 (the maximum size vector/number of rows R can handle) exceeds the 2.06876484e9 rows you are wanting, it is not by much. In practical terms you are likely to run out of RAM long before you get anywhere near that number. And that would be for a single vector. [This link](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/07/17/3-big-data-strategies-for-r/) has some useful tips for dealing with large data. In short, you will have to process your data in chunks. I recommend searching SO and elsewhere for strategies to deal with big data. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: @Greg - yes, read the OP's first comment.

Comment: @OliviaViVi  _"my R was aborted while I run the function"_  What error did R give you?  While the function does work on your sample, I suspect [@LTyrone](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2530121) is right about exceeding size limits with your actual dataset.

Comment: @Greg, Yes I think Tyron was right about the RAM being run out as my Google also crashes together with R, the R code also hasn't given back anything before it said aborted :( .

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I have [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78039650/7) my **Solution** with an *astronomical* improvement over the [iterative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78039650/6).  When fed a *massive* dataset, comparable in size to your own, the new solution completes in about **half a minute**:

```r
# Original dimensions of your dataset.
n_rows <- 32580
n_cols <- 63498

n_vals <- n_rows * n_cols
n_vals
```

> ```
> [1] 2068764840
> ```

```r
# Redistribute so many values among just a few columns, for clarity.
n_cols <- 5
n_rows <- ceiling(n_vals / n_cols)

data_path <- data.table(
    V1               = 1:n_rows,
    Week25_DF16_10   = 1:n_rows + 0.2,
    Week25_DF16_1000 = 1:n_rows + 0.4,
    Week25_DF16_1001 = 1:n_rows + 0.6,
    Week25_DF16_1002 = 1:n_rows + 0.8
)
```

---

## Challenge

As [@LTyrone](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2530121) has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137577686) and you have [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137577796) in the comments, your massive dataset of over 2 billion values...

```r
32580 * 63498
```

> ```
> [1] 2068764840
> ```

...will overburden the elegant [approach](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) with [**`tidyr`**](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org):

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(data_path, starts_with("Week25_"))
```

## Solution

To avoid exceeding your RAM, I suggest this vectorized solution.  It *should* complete in linear time, as [boosted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718317) by [**`data.table`**](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table) itself.

```r
library(data.table)


# ...
# Code to generate 'data_path'.
# ...


# Free unused memory.
gc()


# Identify the 'Week25_*' columns to pivot...
col_prefix <- "Week25_"

# ...and name the output columns: 'name' | 'value'
pivot_to <- c("name", "value")


# Gather the necessary information about the dataset.
all_names <- colnames(data_path)
n_rows <- nrow(data_path)

col_locs <- which(startsWith(all_names, col_prefix))
col_names <- all_names[col_locs]
n_cols <- length(col_locs)


# Flatten the 'Week25_*' values into a vector.
pivot_vals <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(data_path[, col_locs, with = FALSE]))); gc()


# Pivot the original dataset: remove (by reference) the 'Week25_*' columns...
data_path[, (col_locs) := NULL]

# ...and repeat each row, once for every pivoted 'Week25_*' column:
data_path <- data_path[
  # 1, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2, ..., 2, ..., n_rows, n_rows, ..., n_rows
  rep(1:n_rows, each = n_cols)
]


# Free unused memory.
gc()


# Finally append (by reference) the 'name' | 'value' columns.
data_path[, (base::globalenv()$pivot_to) := .(
  # Cycle through the 'Week25_*' names, once for every original row. 
  base::rep(
    # Fully qualify to avoid clashes with column names here...
    base::globalenv()$col_names,
    times = base::globalenv()$n_rows
  ),
  
  # Append the corresponding 'Week25_*' values.
  base::globalenv()$pivot_vals
)]


# Clean up afterwards.
rm(pivot_vals)
gc()
```

## ⚠️ Warning ⚠️

This approach [**modifies `data_path` by reference**](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/assign.html).  That saves a great deal of space, by [avoiding copies](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/assign.html#details) of your massive dataset.  However it also overwrites the initial value of `data_path` forever!

## Result

Given a `data_path` like your sample...

```r
data_path <- structure(
  list(
    V1 = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A3GALT2"),
    Week25_DF16_10 = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1000 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1001 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L),
    Week25_DF16_1002 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = c("data.table","data.frame")
)
```

...this solution *modifies* `data_path` into the following result:

```r
data_path
```

> ```
>          V1             name value
>  1:    A1BG   Week25_DF16_10     0
>  2:    A1BG Week25_DF16_1000     0
>  3:    A1BG Week25_DF16_1001     0
>  4:    A1BG Week25_DF16_1002     0
>  5:    A1CF   Week25_DF16_10     0
>  6:    A1CF Week25_DF16_1000     0
>  7:    A1CF Week25_DF16_1001     0
>  8:    A1CF Week25_DF16_1002     0
>  9:     A2M   Week25_DF16_10     7
> 10:     A2M Week25_DF16_1000     4
> 11:     A2M Week25_DF16_1001     2
> 12:     A2M Week25_DF16_1002     0
> 13:   A2ML1   Week25_DF16_10     0
> 14:   A2ML1 Week25_DF16_1000     0
> 15:   A2ML1 Week25_DF16_1001     0
> 16:   A2ML1 Week25_DF16_1002     0
> 17: A3GALT2   Week25_DF16_10     0
> 18: A3GALT2 Week25_DF16_1000     0
> 19: A3GALT2 Week25_DF16_1001     0
> 20: A3GALT2 Week25_DF16_1002     0
> ```

### Note

This is consistent with the **`tidyr`** output:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)


# ...
# Code to generate 'data_path'.
# ...


# This must run BEFORE 'data_path' is modified.
tidy_out <- pivot_longer(data_path, starts_with("Week25_"))


# ...
# My solution above.
# ...


# Compare the outputs.
identical(data_path, as.data.table(tidy_out))
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```