# force the evaluation of .SD in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lazy-evaluation

In order to debug `j` in data.table I prefer to interactively inspect the resulting -`by`- dt´s with `browser()`. [SO 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667984/can-sd-be-viewed-from-a-browser-within-data-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) adressed this issue and I understand that .SD must be invoked in `j` in order for all columns to be evaluated. I use Rstudio and using the [SO 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667984/can-sd-be-viewed-from-a-browser-within-data-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) method, there are two problems:

1. The environment pane is not updated reflecting the browser environment
2. I often encounter the following error msg

> ```
> Error: option error has NULL value
> In addition: Warning message:
> In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
>   restarting interrupted promise evaluation
> ```

I can get around this by doing:

```
f <- function(sd=force(.SD),.env = parent.frame(n = 1)) {
  by = .env$.BY;
  i = .env$.I;
  sd = .env$.SD;
  grp = .env$.GRP;
  N = .env$.N;
  browser()
}
library (data.table)

setDT(copy(mtcars))[,f(.SD),by=.(gear)]
```

But - in the `data.table` spirit of keeping things short and sweet- can I somehow force (the `force` in `f` does not work) the evaluation of .SD in the call to `f` so that the final code could run:

```
setDT(copy(mtcars))[,f(),by=.(gear)]
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know,
`data.table` needs to explicitly see `.SD` somewhere in the code passed to `j`,
otherwise it won't even expose it in the environment it creates for the execution.
See for example [this question and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530948/why-does-data-table-j-have-a-different-environment-when-directly-calling-mget).

Why don't you create a different helper function that always specifies `.SD` in `j`?
Something like:

```
dt_debugger <- function(dt, ...) {
  f <- function(..., .caller_env = parent.frame()) {
    by <- .caller_env$.BY;
    i <- .caller_env$.I;
    sd <- .caller_env$.SD;
    grp <- .caller_env$.GRP;
    N <- .caller_env$.N;
    browser()
  }

  dt[..., j = f(.SD)]
}

dt_debugger(as.data.table(mtcars), by = .(gear))
```